# How can I specify a long list of math operators?

Tags: macros, programming, math-operators

The preambles of my LaTeX documents often include many many lines of `\DeclareMathOperator` instructions, e.g.

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rep}{Rep}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tet}{Tet}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Maps}{Maps}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Diff}{Diff}
```

Is there a nice way to *map* some macro over a list, so I could do this more concisely, and with less copying and pasting when I add a new math operator?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Updated solution using the features of [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which has essentially implemented the “`\MapCommand`” and named it `\forcsvlist`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\DeclareMyOperator}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}
}
\newcommand{\DeclareMathOperators}{\forcsvlist{\DeclareMyOperator}}

\DeclareMathOperators{Rep,Tet,Maps,Diff}

\begin{document}
Operators: $\Rep, \Tet, \Maps, \Diff$
\end{document}
```

“For historical reasons”, I leave my original answer bellow.

---

Combining the previous answers from Grigory and Andrew I was able to come up with the following somewhat cleaner implementation which also exposes a nice user interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ops@declare#1{%
  \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}
}
\def\ops@scan#1,{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \let\ops@next\relax
  \else
    \ops@declare{#1}\let\ops@next\ops@scan
  \fi\ops@next
}
\newcommand{\DeclareMathOperators}[1]{\ops@scan#1,\relax,}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperators{Rep,Tet,Maps,Diff}

\begin{document}
Operators: $\Rep, \Tet, \Maps, \Diff$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! (and some more characters to take me over the limit)

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that it would result in lots of code duplication if I wanted to also do something like define \cX as \mathcal{X} for each letter X.

Comment: Following the scheme above it wont be difficult to define a more general `\MapCommand{\Cmd}{a,b,c}` which expands to `\Cmd{a}\Cmd{b}\Cmd{c}`.

Comment: @Juan: This is very useful! Unfortunately, I don't have much practice with TeX/LaTeX beyond writing my documents in it and defining the occasional macro, so I don't really understand how your solution works, and I'm not able to generalize it to something like a `\MapCommand` (which is what I've been trying to do to no avail). I was wondering if you could give a hint as to how to do it, or even a full implementation? Of course, I know the value of learning to do something myself, but in this case I'm sufficiently exasperated to ask for a solution that I will then try to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Zev: I added a new simpler solution which is more robust and hopefully much more easy to understand. It relies on the `etoolbox` package and its command `\forcsvlist` which is basically the "map command" that you are looking for. Have a look at the documentation of that package.

Comment: @Juan: Thanks so much! etoolbox looks like a very powerful package.

Answer (score 24):

There are several ways to do it using different programming facilities of different packages. Here's what it looks like using the LaTeX2e kernel command `\@for` to map over a comma-separated list:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MakeMathOperators[1]{%
  \@for\@ii:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\@ii
  }%
}
\makeatother
\MakeMathOperators{
  \rep  {Rep}  ,
  \tet  {Tet}  ,
  \maps {Maps}
}
```

Comment: This is great. I like that it's clear how to generalize this solution.

Comment: Talking of generalising, I just generalised this to do a step-through iteration on beamer slides (`x^{\step{2,3,4,5}}`).  I didn't know about the `\@for` before.  Very useful! +1

Comment: I really wish this were the selected answer, in looking for a source about what the @ symbol is used for. This response plus [saving a 100 tokens](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/saving-a-100-tokens-worth-is-it-worth-it) and [internal LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465) were key to my comprehending the role of this symbol and how to react when I run across it in others' code. Grazie! @WillRobertson

Answer (score 13):

Combining the [previous answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators/361#361) with the [ones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-is-the-best-way-to-scan-over-a-list-of-somethings/1206#1206) to the related question about [scanning over a list of somethings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-is-the-best-way-to-scan-over-a-list-of-somethings) I came up with the following solution, using `etoolbox` version 2.0 (2010-08-21) or later.

```
\newcommand{\define}[4]{\expandafter#1\csname#3#4\endcsname{#2{#4}}}
\forcsvlist{\define{\DeclareMathOperator}{}{}}{Rep, Tet, Maps, Diff}
\forcsvlist{\define{\newcommand}{\mathcal}{c}}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K}
```

The last line defines `\cA` as `\mathcal{A}` for all letters in the list.

If one wants a different list separator, e.g. `;`, one can use `\DeclareListParser*{\formylist}{;}` and then replace `\forcvslist` with `\formylist`.

Comment: compact and very extensible - very nice

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably do this differently if I were coding it today (as I've learnt a lot more about TeX in the last decade), but here's something like how I did it for my thesis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\my@shift#1:#2.{#1}
\def\my@trunc#1:#2.{#2}
\def\my@void{}\relax

\newcommand{\Mops}[1]{%
 \def\my@test{}\relax
 \def\my@list{#1:}\relax
 \loop\ifx\my@test\my@void\relax
 \edef\my@elt{\expandafter\my@shift\my@list.}\relax
 \edef\my@list{\expandafter\my@trunc\my@list.}\relax
 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\csname \expandafter\my@elt\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter}\expandafter{\my@elt}
 \ifx\my@list\my@void
 \def\my@test{t}
 \fi
 \repeat}

\makeatother

\Mops{Det:Diff:Rep}

\begin{document}
\(\Det \Diff \Rep\)
\end{document}
```

The test in the loop could probably be cleaned up, and that is a rather horrendous number of `\expandafter`s!  But it works.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence about the `\expandafter`.

Answer (score 3):

Put the whole list of unabbreviated `\DeclareMathOperator` macros in a file `myoperators.sty`, somewhere in your latex path (I suggest `~/tex/`).  Then add `\usepackage{myoperators}` at the top of any `.tex` file that uses those operators.

Do this for any macro you use more than once.

Comment: I used to do this. Then I started having collaborators. Sometimes keeping everything in one file has its advantages.

Comment: You can deal with the collaborators problem by having the files you've `\input` get automatically inserted into the .tex file. The LaTeX compilation system [Rubber](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/) has a `-o expand option`, for [source file expansion](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/doc_4.html#SEC15).

Comment: @Willie: only as long as you ship files via email. When using version control or syncing (such as shared Dropbox folders) along with file system symlinks, using more than one file is really quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution from Kevin Walker's LaTeX preambles:

```
% tricky way to iterate macros over a list
\def\semicolon{;}
\def\applytolist#1{
    \expandafter\def\csname multi#1\endcsname##1{
        \def\multiack{##1}\ifx\multiack\semicolon
            \def\next{\relax}
        \else
            \csname #1\endcsname{##1}
            \def\next{\csname multi#1\endcsname}
        \fi
        \next}
    \csname multi#1\endcsname}

% \DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr} etc.
\def\declaremathop#1{\expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}}

\applytolist{declaremathop}{pr}{im}{gl}{ev}{coinv}{tr}{rot}{Eq}{obj}{mor}{ob}{Rep}{Tet}{cat}{Maps}{Diff}{Homeo}{sign}{supp}{Nbd}{res}{rad};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're looking for, but I'd probably write the quick hack:

```
\newcommand{\OP}[1]{\DeclareMathOperator{#1}}
\OP{Rep}
\OP{Tet}
```

and so forth. Moreover if I were to use these a lot, I'd just write them once and include them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
\def\deflist#1{\ifx#1\stop\let\next=\kill\else\let\next=\parse\fi\next{#1}}  
\def\kill#1{\relax}
\def\parse#1#2{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#2}}\deflist}

\deflist
\holim{holim}
\hocolim{hocolim}
\stop
```

works (although I can't recommend using such tricks).