# Using \nameref within \path

Tags: expansion, urls, paths

### Background

Looking to apply a consistent style to file and directory names. The book's appendix has a subsection for every file referenced by the book. Every subsection has a label whose value is that of the subsection. In this fashion, changing the label will change all the references throughout the book, accordingly.

### Problem

The `\path{}` command in the URL package takes an argument and applies its style while taking into consideration backslashes. For example, the following works as expected:

```
\path{cities.jsp}
```

What would be ideal is:

```
\path{\nameref{sub:cities.jsp}}
```

This will output `\nameref{sub:cities.jsp}` into the document, rather than the desired value of `cities.jsp`.

The purpose is so that if I change my mind about the file name, all I need to do is change the label "sub:cities.jsp" to "sub:city.jsp", for example, and the entire document now references "city.jsp". I use a subsection so that hyperlinks are automatically applied.

### Question

How can a parameter be added to `\path{}` that first expands `\nameref` before passing the argument to `\path{}`? That is, how can I write the following:

```
\filename{sub:cities.jsp}
```

And have it become:

```
\path{cities.jsp}
```

I have tried a number of variations, but I do not understand how to use `expandafter` with parameters (and even the simplest `expandafter` examples that I can find are Latin to me). I also want to keep the `\path` command unchanged (as I use it for directory names, not file names) and add a new command `\filename` that references the files by their corresponding subsection. Examples from the preamble:

#### Attempt #1

```
% \newcommand{\filename}[1]{\path{#1}}
% \expandafter\filename\path
\expandafter\def\filename#1{\nameref{#1}} \path
```

The first line gives me the `\filename` command, but does not expand the parameter until `\path` looks at it, which is not surprising.

The second line fails because the parameter is not taken into consideration, nor `\nameref`.

The third line generates "Undefined control sequence" errors.

#### Attempt #2

```
\def \filename #1{\nameref{#1}}
\expandafter\def\filename \path
```

### Related

- [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter)
- http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf

Comment: Not an answer, but avoiding the problem: have you considered using \texttt{...} instead of \path? It depends on what kind of characters you expect to occur or not occur in your filenames.

Comment: @Ulrich: I have not considered that. I would like to use `\path` so that, when time comes, I can use the URL package to change the font of all paths everywhere. If I use a mix of `\path` and `\texttt`, then I have to change two things. Also, `\texttt` is formatting, it does not describe the content. An interesting, solution, though, if I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, your intention is: just one place for the file name. If needed, you only have to make a change at this place. That's very good! However, I would not choose subsection headings within the document body for such places.

I suggest to define macros for file names all at one place in the preamble.

Once you have done this, you could easily use `\expandafter`. Further I guess it may be harder to use `\expandafter` with referencing commands such as `\nameref` or `\autoref`. With normal macros it's easy. For example

```
\newcommand*{\expath}[1]{\expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}}
```

calls `\path` with the expanded file name variable as argument.

Complete minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand*{\filecities}{cities.jsp}
\newcommand*{\expath}[1]{\expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\subsection{\filecities}
The file name is \expath{\filecities}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the file name changes, just modify `\filecities`.

I've tested the same way of expansion with `\nameref` but it didn't work - but in any case I would not depend on definitions in headings within the body, for such work I rely on the preamble.

Comment: The point of using the `\path` (at least from the previous question) was to allow `c:\foo` paths.

Comment: @TH.: This `\expath` (for the file name) works also with `c:\foo`. Besides that: Dave may still use `\path` but the point here is a `\filename` macro. I expect, unless stated otherwise, a file name doesn't contain a complete path. However, also this would be no problem.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this solution only works for “neat” filenames not containing “_”, “%” etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a more robust approach, using the `\urldef` macro of the `url` package to define filename macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\urldef\citiesjsp\path{cities.jsp}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A Section}

\subsection{\citiesjsp}
\label{sub:citiesjsp}

The filename is \nameref{sub:citiesjsp}.

\end{document}
```

Note that macros defined with `\urldef` are robust. As a consequence, they can smoothly be used in moving arguments (e.g. in the argument of `\subsection`). Moreover, I think that `\nameref` is quite a good choice for referencing filenames in the current context since you get not only filenames, but also hyperlinks to the corresponding subsection headings.

The resulting output is:

[image]