# Use path replacement command inside tikzpicture/pgfplots table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, expansion

After using the answer of [Using \nameref within \path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/using-nameref-within-path) I tried to use that command inside a 'pgfplots' table as file name. Here's the (shortened) code:

```
\newcommand*{\expath}[1]{/Users/jo/{#1}}

\expath{folder/file.csv} %line 3

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot
table {\expath{folder/file.csv}}; %line 8
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

While line 3 prints `/Users/jo/folder/file.csv` as expected, line 8 throws an error saying `could not read table file '/Users/jo/{folder/file.csv}'` (note the extra `{` and `}`).

What's going wrong here?

**Update:**
Using `\expath` inside another command like `\input` is also not working. The error message there prints the right path to a file (no extra brackets there), but still says `file not found`...

```
\input{\expath{subpath/to/file.tex}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have braces around `#1` in the `\newcommand`, so they get added to the path. Just remove those, i.e.

```
\newcommand*{\expath}[1]{/Users/jo/#1}
```