# I'm a cargo cult programmer ...

Tags: packages

... because I don't know why this works

```
\def\my@addextraoption#1{%
    \xdef\my@extraoptions{%
        \@ifundefined{my@extraoptions}\@empty\my@extraoptions,%
         \zap@space#1 \@empty}}
\DeclareOption*{\my@addextraoption\CurrentOption}
```

but this doesn't:

```
\DeclareOption*{%
    \xdef\my@extraoptions{%
        \@ifundefined{my@extraoptions}\@empty\my@extraoptions,%
         \zap@space\CurrentOption \@empty}}
```

The latter gives me this error:

```
! Argument of \zap@space has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.110 \ProcessOptions\relax
```

So what gives here? I tend to enable my cargo cult programmer bit when I get that inscrutable `Argument of \@foo has an extra }.` message (or some other inscrutable message coming deep from the core of TeX/LaTeX). Eventually I find some syntax that appears to work, and then I test it to death to make sure it really does work.

There has to be a better way than enabling my cargo cult programmer bit. TeX/LaTeX is one of the very few languages that triggers that bit inside me. TeX/LaTeX ranks right up there with JCL (yes, that does date me, doesn't it) and postscript/forth in that regard.

Comment: Can you add a minimal (non-working), what you posted works for me with no errors, so my first thoughts you are getting these errors from some redefinitions in a package.

Comment: @Yiannis: Odd, I got errors as reported.

Comment: The title does not give useful information.

Comment: @xport: Google the term. Most programmers are cargo cult programmers. They cut and paste dead code because buried in that dead code is some live code that does solve the problem, then they add even more stuff to that already bloated code, and to top it off they wave a dead chicken to eventually 'solve' the problem. LaTeX has this nasty tendency to bring out the cargo cult programmer in even the best of us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's to do with when TeX swallows spaces.  There's actually two parts to the "when".  The first thing to know is that TeX swallows spaces when it reads the input.  The second thing to know is that TeX swallows spaces after a command name.  Putting those two together, we see that TeX swallows a space when it follows a command name **in the input** but **not** when already-read code is reinserted in to the stream.  Let's now examine the two cases:

1. `\zap@space#1 \@empty`  When TeX reads this, it doesn't know that `#1` is going to be a command.  For all it knows, `#1` could be a pile of fetid dingo's kidneys.  So it doesn't swallow the space.  Thus when this code is executed, TeX sees: `\zap@space\CurrentOption \@empty` *with the space still there*.  Hence, everyone is happy.
2. `\zap@space\CurrentOption \@empty`  When TeX reads this, it *knows* that `\CurrentOption` is a command, so it swallows the space.  Thus the actual code that the processor sees is `\zap@space\CurrentOption\@empty` and there's no space to zap, so `\zap@space` complains.

There are probably many solutions.  A simple one is to ensure that when TeX sees that space then it isn't in "space swallowing" mode.  To do this, we have to figure out a way to make it so that the last thing that TeX saw before the space *isn't* a command.  A common way to do this is to put an empty group there: `\zap@space\CurrentOption{} \@empty` works.

(*Edit:*) As Philippe points out, the above adds the brace to the argument of `\my@extraoptions`.  Here's one that doesn't, with fewer `\expandafters`:

```
\expandafter\zap@space\expandafter\CurrentOption\space\@empty
```

but in fact, looking at the output of `\my@extraoptions` then I think that there is something wrong with your `\@ifundefined` bit.  Here's what I *think* you are after:

```
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\DeclareOption*{%
  \edef\@temp{%
    \xdef\noexpand\my@extraoptions{%
    \@ifundefined{my@extraoptions}{}{\my@extraoptions,}%
    \noexpand\zap@space\CurrentOption\space\noexpand\@empty}}
  \@temp
}

\ProcessOptions

\show\my@extraoptions
```

with a calling program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hello,world]{test}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

In the log file, I get that `\my@extraoptions` is `hello,world`.  With your original code, I got `,hello,world` - that is, with an initial comma.

As well as correcting the `\@ifundefined`, I've taken the alternative route through expansion.  Rather than an excess of `\expandafter`s, I've used an `\edef` to define a temporary macro which expands stuff as necessary (with a few expansions inhibited with `\noexpand`) which is then called straight after to do the actual definition.

(This is a trick I learnt here ... [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter) ... after seeing a macro with about 20 `\expandafter`s be condensed to just one.  That's also where *I* was accused of being a Cargo Cult Programmer!)

Comment: PS I'm unashamedly a Cargo Cult Programmer myself.  One reason I like this place is that it's a gentle way of finding out more.

Comment: Using `\space` is indeed better than `\@iden`.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. One remaining question: You don't have a `noexpand` in front of the `\xdef`. Since this is in an `\edef`, it looks like your solution will refine `\noexpand` -- but it obviously doesn't. Putting a `\noexpand` in front of the `\xdef` also works. That `\noexpand\xdef` is apparently a gratuitous use of noexpand, but I'm a bit queasy without it.

Comment: @David: The token `\xdef` is not expandable, so the expansion operator ignores it.  One could say that `\xdef` _comes with_ a `\noexpand` already built in.  When the macro is _called_, then it gets processed.  You could try putting `\show\@temp` with and without the `\noexpand` in front of the `\xdef` (and try removing a few other `\noexpand`s just to see what effect they have).

Comment: I know what those other `\noexpand`s do. I presume this non-expandability pertains only to TeX primitives, and only to some of them. All members of the def family, I assume, what else is unexpandable?   It seems to me that a lot of this cargo cult stuff could be avoided if TeX supplied an \expand primitive. Is there a way to force an expansion, sans things like this edef trick?

Comment: @David: Everything gets expanded in its time, so by "force an expansion" you mean that you want something expanded before its time.  To do that, you need TeX to be in an expansive mood, which means that it is either processing as normal or inside an `\edef` (or something similar).  There's no way to force an expansion if TeX isn't feeling expansive (such as inside a `\def`) which is why tricks like the above are used.  I recommend that you browse "TeX by Topic" (`texdoc texbytopic`).  That and this site are my main resources for learning about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8):

The definition of `\zap@space` is

```
\def\zap@space#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\zap@space\fi
  #2}
```

This means that `\zap@space` kills spaces one by one, but needs to end with a space followed by `\@empty`. When you write `\zap@space#1 \@empty`, this will be the case because `#1` is replaced by its content. But when you write `\zap@space\CurrentOption \@empty`, TeX eats the space after `\CurrentOption` (as it always does for spaces after multi-letter macros), and so it's equivalent to `\zap@space\CurrentOption\@empty` which is incorrect as there's no space before `\@empty`.

I cannot be sure without a complete example of your code, but I think this will work in your case:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zap@space\expandafter\@iden\expandafter{\CurrentOption} \@empty
```

The `\@iden` macro expands to give its argument (the definition is `\def\@iden#1{#1}`) so `\@iden{\CurrentOption}` will be the same as `\CurrentOption`, but because of the ending brace, the space after it is kept. But as you need to expand \@iden, you have to use `\expandafter`. For the spaces of `\CurrentOption` to be trimmed, you also need an additionnal two `\expandafter` before (you won't get an error if you omit them, but no spaces will be zapped).

Added after seeing Andrew's answer: the advantage of this compared to what Andrew suggested (`\zap@space\CurrentOption{} \@empty`) is that no spurious braces are added to the result.

Comment: Good point about the braces!  I've edited mine to provide an alternative without them.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to be a comment, and too old to merit an update to my question.

Three years after the fact, I've learned much about `\expandafter`, and perhaps even why I have to do `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter ... \foo \expandafter ...`

I think my cargo cult programming experiences with TeX/LaTeX can be summarized in two words: *leaky abstractions*. By way of analogy, I use macports, fink, and homebrew on my Mac. Which system do I like best? It's certainly not the system I'm using now. It's one of the two systems that I'm not using. All three of those tools ⟨defamatory words elided⟩.

Regarding TeX/LaTeX: Those defamatory words most definitely apply. There are far too many leaky abstractions from a 1960s era macro-based system. It's those macros and the leaky abstractions that result that toggle my cargo cult programming bit.

However, compared to other tools (e.g., stuff from microstuff), I still very much prefer TeX/LaTeX for writing documents. With regard to writing the underlying tools that authors need, that's a different question.