# TikZ 3 space between options and named angle in a label no more allowed

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

### Release comparison

In version 2.10 of TikZ you could write:

```
\coordinate [label={[red] center:$P$}] (x) at (0,0);
```

but in the latest release (version 3.0.0) you'll get an error (`unknown function 'center'`) unless you write it without any space between the `[options]` and the `<angle>`:

```
\coordinate [label={[red]center:$P$}] (x) at (0,0);
```

On the contrary, you can still write it as before if the `<angle>` is a number:

```
\coordinate [label={[red] 30:$P$}] (x) at (0,0);
```

### Question

Is this a bug or a desired behaviour?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\coordinate [label={[red] center:$P$}] (a) at (0,0); % this doesn't work
\coordinate [label={[red]center:$P$}]  (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate [label={[red] 30:$P$}]     (c) at (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I filed a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/291/) on Sourceforge. Even if this is not actually a bug, I think there is a compatibility issue with older codes that should be solved.

Comment: _All_ of these don't work for me, but maybe I'm missing a library you've loaded or some other setup/options you've configured. Could you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so the community can take a look at what might be going on?

Comment: @PaulGessler, you are right! I forgot the coordinate `<name>`.

Comment: @Adam you are wrong. Please test the code by yourself before suggesting to close it as off topic. There is actually an issue. I forgot to include a particular element in the MWE only, but I fixed it almost one month ago. Please, give it a try and let me know if it works or not (you have to uncomment the first coordinate to see the wrong behaviour).

Comment: Sorry, @Luigi! I misread the comments. I've voted to reopen. And you're right. In the future I'll be sure to test the code. `:)` Sorry!

Comment: @Adam never mind! Maybe that comment was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amazingly finding the problem was much easier than using the `\ignorespaces`,  thanks to David Carlisle on chat, realizing my stupid mistake that `\zap@space` should be utilized. More fun is here if you haven't yet [I'm a cargo cult programmer ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/im-a-cargo-cult-programmer)

Anyway, the reason for the error is that the code is, with all respect, looking like unfinished there. The space gobbling is not performed so when you send a whitespace in front of `center` it is compared with a macro defined as

```
\def\tikz@on@text{center}
```

So when you `\ifx` them they don't match and TikZ thinks you sent an angle or an anchor. You know the rest. As a working example I tried to gobble the initial spaces for testing and David Carlisle fixed my gobble mechanism. The macro opening is the changed part that was originally located on line 701 of `tikz.code.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter

\tikzset{tikz@label@post/.code={% The code has 2 args here WHY? Line 701
  \edef\tikz@label@angle{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
                         \zap@space%
                         \expandafter\tikz@label@angle\space \@empty}%
  \csname tikz@label@angle@is@\tikz@label@angle\endcsname%
  \ifx\tikz@label@angle\tikz@on@text%
    \def\tikz@node@at{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}%
    \def\tikz@anchor{center}%
  \else%
    \iftikz@absolute%
      \pgftransformreset%
      \pgf@process{%
        \pgfpointshapeborder{\tikzlastnode}%
        {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}{\pgfpointpolar{\tikz@label@angle}{1pt}}}}%
      \edef\tikz@node@at{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
      \tikz@compute@direction{\tikz@label@angle}%
      \tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{\tikz@label@angle}{#1}}}%  
    \else%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{\tikz@label@angle}}%
      \edef\tikz@node@at{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
      \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}%
      \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
      \tikz@label@simplefalse%
      \iftikz@fullytransformed%
        \tikz@label@simpletrue%
      \else
        \ifdim\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb\relax%
          \ifdim\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb\relax%
            \tikz@label@simpletrue%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \iftikz@label@simple%  
        \tikz@compute@direction{\tikz@label@angle}%
        \tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{\tikz@label@angle}{#1}}}%  
      \else%
        \pgf@process{\pgfpointnormalised{%
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}}{\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}}}}%
        \edef\pgf@marshal{%
          \noexpand\tikz@addtransform{\noexpand\pgftransformshift{\noexpand\pgfpointscale{#1}{
                \noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}}}}%
        \pgf@marshal%
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
        \pgf@x=\pgf@yc%
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@xc%
        \tikz@auto@anchor%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label={[red]     center:$P$}] (a) at (0,0); % this works
\coordinate [label={[red]center:$P$}]  (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate [label={[red] 30:$P$}]     (c) at (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]