# \expandafter, \csname issue related to test for macro being defined

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

Just when I think I starting to understand `\expandafter` I run into this problem where I am trying to test if `\ConditionG`, `\ConditionH`, etc are defined in a loop. I tried all the combinations I could think of and am not able to get this to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

%\def\ConditionG{}% This should show up as undefined
\def\ConditionH{}

\foreach \i in {G, H}{
    \expandafter\ifdefined\csname Condition\i\endcsname% Incorrect Results: everything defined
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is defined\par
    \else
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is not defined\par
    \fi
}

\hrule
\foreach \i in {G, H}{% Using etoolbox
    \ifdef{\expandafter\csname Condition\i\endcsname}{% Incorrect Results: everything defined
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is defined\par
    }{
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is not defined\par
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Joseph's detailed explanation regarding [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter) makes sense to me, but can't seem to apply that to my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `\ifcsname` ... `\endcsname` instead.

Note that `\csname` ... `\endcsname` makes the undefined control sequence to be `\relax`. See TeXbook Exercise 7.7:

> When `\csname` is used to define a
>   control sequence for the first time,
>   that control sequence is made
>   equivalent to `\relax` until it is
>   redefined.

You can test a macro like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\ConditionH{}

\foreach \i in {G, H}{
    \ifcsname Condition\i\endcsname
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is defined\par
    \else
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is not defined\par
    \fi
}

\hrule
\foreach \i in {G, H}{% Using etoolbox
    \ifcsdef{Condition\i}{%
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is defined\par
    }{
        \textbackslash Condition\i\ is not defined\par
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And without eTeX, people often use `\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\relax` ... `\fi` to test a macro. In LaTeX2e, this is what `\@ifundefined` do.

Comment: As I say in my answer, the approach of `\@ifundefined` works expandably but fills up the hash table, whereas using a group avoids the hash table issue at the cost of not being expandable.

Comment: @Joseph: in fact, I realized that even `\newcount\i \def\test{\advance\i by 1{\csname foo\the\i\endcsname}\test}\test` fills the hash table (and apparently, the control sequence is put in the hash table even when scanned within a `\def` (or any token list).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Leo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21221), without e-TeX the usual test for an undefined control sequence is

```
\def\ifundefined#1{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

This works by doing the `\csname` ... `\endcsname` inside a group and testing if the meaning of the name we want is equal to `\relax`. The group means that if the control sequence was undefined then it is only made into `\relax` within the test, and not globally. The downside is that this test is not expandable. Of course, it cannot tell the difference between an undefined control sequence and one that is deliberately equal to `\relax`. (The `\expandafter`s here make the `\csname` happen before the `\ifx`, which itself takes place before the `\endgroup`.)

A side note. In the LaTeX2e kernel, `\@ifundefined` does not use the grouping approach, so that it has an expandable test. That means that each time you use `\@ifundefined` with a previously-undefined control sequence, it does end up defined as `\relax`.

Comment: You can also write this a little shorter by placing the `\endgroup` commands in the clauses:  `\begingroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other, more relevant answers, I want to mention that your second code block uses `\expandafter` redundantly.  The result of `\expandafter\csname Condition\i\endcsname` is just `\csname Condition\i\endcsname`, since the "C" is expanded before `\csname`.  As it turns out, `\csname` itself continues the expansion and eventually gets `\i`, but for example something like `\expandafter\toks0={\i}` will backfire (it expands the 0, not the `\i`).

It's possible you intended to use `\expandafter` as an "execute this" command, as though its function were: `\expandafter\a\b` first expands `\b`, then expands `\a`.  In fact, all it does is expand `\b` "in place", without touching `\a`; if `\a` does expand, that is because TeX's own "mouth" continues processing the input, expanding as it goes.  If `\a` is not expandable but executable, then it is executed, unless that is inhibited, like in `\edef`.  For example, `\edef\macro{\def\a{a}\a}` does not define `\macro=a`, but rather gives an error (assuming `\a` was not defined already) since it doesn't expand `\def` and thus, doesn't know that the `\a` after it is not intended to be expanded.  No amount of `\expandafter`s will change this.

If that was not your intention, please take my lecture to be directed at the audience.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Am hoping that one of these days I can fully comprehend `\expandafter`.