# Print name of command, defined by \csname

Tags: expansion

First off: I do not understand `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` completely which is probably the main problem. I have found a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter) that explains what it does, but still I cannot seem to make it work.

I simply want to print the name of a command using `\csname` like this:

```
\def\str{String}

Command: \csname str\endcsname.\par
End command.
```

This prints the contents of `\str` (String), but I want to prevent the last expansion. I thought this would work:

```
Command: \expandafter\noexpand\csname str\endcsname.\par
```

This would first expand `\csname` to `\str`, and then `\noexpand` should prohibit the next expansion. But apparently, this gives a blank output, which is actually very strange.

So I want to expand `\csname`, but not `\str`.

---

EDIT: Few things to consider I did not know they were important (or just did not thought through):

1. It's for writing to a file.
2. It also has to work for non-`\csname` based commands.

Thus the code changes to:

```
\immediate\write\file{Command: \expandafter\noexpand\csname str\endcsname}
```

Which works (as egreg said), but does not work with

```
\immediate\write\file{Command: \expandafter\noexpand\str}
```

This is needed because I need to make a command that shows the command. In total it should look like this:

```
\newcommand\writecmd[1]{
  \immediate\write\file{\expandafter\noexpand#1}
}

\def\str{Blahblah}

\writecmd{\str}
\writecmd{\csname str\endcsname}
```

This outputs

```
Blahblah
\str
```

which is almost what I needed. If there is a workaround, that's fine too. Mind that the command `\writecmd` is in my program a little bit more extensive.

Comment: The `\expandafter\noexpand` method would be good for writing in a file; the command name would be followed by a space, which is not the case for `\expandafter\string`.

Comment: Oh great.. Yeah it is actually for writing to a file. I was just testing it without having to use a file.. But there seems to be another problem: it has to show the command regardless if `\csname` is there or just the command.. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  Command: \expandafter\string\csname str\endcsname.\par
```

`\noexpand` prevents expansion by making the command temporarily act like `\relax`
If you had gone

```
  Command: \relax\par
```

It would not have printed "`\relax`" You need

```
  Command: \string\relax\par
```

for that.

So first you want to do the csname to get the command name token then you want to use `\string` on that to get back to where you started, but with a backslash, so

```
  Command: \expandafter\string\csname str\endcsname.\par
```

Or of course

```
  Command: \@backslashchar str.\par
```

---

For your updated question, you want to test for `\csname`

```
\def\foo#1{%
\ifx\csname#1%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\string
\expandafter\csname
\else
\string#1%
\fi}

\immediate\write20{\foo\fffff}


\immediate\write20{\foo\csname fff99ff\endcsname}

\bye
```

produces

```
$ tex cs88
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)
(./cs88.tex
\fffff
\fff99ff
 )
No pages of output.
```

Comment: `\csname @backslashchar\endcsname str.\par` :)

Comment: Thanks, I've learned something new again `:)`, but it was not what I needed. My question was sadly not correct. Look for the edit and comment. Thanks though.

Comment: Wouldn't `detokenize` do the job here?

Comment: @percusse far too modern for me:-)

Comment: @Didii don't undo it now but actually it's better, if you decide you didn't ask the right question, to accept the answer you didn't want and ask another question on site, otherwise when people come to the site later the answers look silly and/or wrong as they are answering a question that is no longer there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's right. But it seemed stupid to ask a new question for only the update. I'll do that in the future `:)` Thanks a lot for the answer! Seems a bit too long for what I'm after `:p` but works flawlessly!

Comment: So basically, to test whether your command is defined by `\csname` or `\ `, you can run the test `\ifx\csname<cmd>` right?

Comment: not really, `#1` there will be the first token after `\foo` which in the examples are `\fffff` in the first case (not `\ `) and `\csname` (not `\csname fff99ff\endcsname`) in the second case. So the `\ifx` test tests if `#1` _is_  `\csname` (or actually is any command with the same definition as `\csname`) and if so does `\expandafter\string`  as in my first example otherwise just does `\string`. The extra `\expandafter` just make the `\else` and `\fi` expand away before starting the csname which isn't strictly necessary in this case but it's more confusing if you don't do it.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I get it: `\foo` absorbs the next argument (in case of `\csname` it's `\csname`, in case of cmd it's the command). Checks whether it's `\csname` or not, and then the 2 first arguments get replaced by the appropriate command. Clever `:)`