# Define command either with or without \csname

Tags: expansion

I'm trying to do the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64496/print-name-of-command-defined-by-csname), but with `\def`, `\gdef` or `\xdef` instead.

Very quick summary of the other question:
I wanted to print the command (not the contents of the command) regardless of it being defined by `\csname` or not. Solution was to check whether the first string is `\csname` or the command.

So `\def` needs an `\expandafter` if used with `\csname`. If not then everything is ok:

```
\def\str{String}
\expandafter\def\csname str\endcsname{String}
```

Both are correct. But if I wanted to change `\str` or `\csname str\endcsname` with an argument (`#1`). Now it's not known whether I need to use `\expandafter` or not. If used when not needed, it results in an error. I wrote this (in analogy with the other question)

```
\def\defcmd#1{
  \ifx\csname#1
    \expandafter\def\csname
  \else
    \def#1
  \fi
}

\defcmd\str{String}
\defcmd\csname str\endcsname{String}
```

This will absorb the first string after `\defcmd` as argument (`#1`), check whether it's `\csname` or anything else and will then replace itself either with `\expandafter\def` or `\def` and place the argument back.
When running that code, no problem at all. But when I try to output the command (either directly or in a file) I get the following error:

```
! Use of \str doesn't match its definition
l.24
```

And I have no clue why that is. (l.24 is one line after the use of `\str`)

Comment: you didn't put in the extra expandafter: I said in comments in the other question that it is confusing if you don't:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see what happens in the two cases.

### `\defcmd\str{foo}`

This becomes

```
\ifx\csname\str\expandafter\def\csname\else\def\str\fi
```

and the test is false, so what remains in the input stream is

```
\def\str\fi{foo}
```

which is perfectly acceptable for TeX, but has two issues: the token `\str` *must* be followed by `\fi` and there will also be an error about a forgotten `\fi`

### `\defcmd\csname str\endcsname{foo}`

This becomes

```
\ifx\csname\csname\expandafter\def\csname\else\def\csname\fi str\endcsname{foo}
```

and TeX will leave in the input stream

```
\expandafter\def\csname\else\def\csname\fi str\endcsname{foo}
```

Now `\expandafter` expands `\csname` which will get rid of what is between `\else` and `\fi`, resulting in

```
\def\str{foo}
```

as required.

### Solution

We have to get rid of the `\fi` before `\def` is executed. One way has been shown by David. Alternatively:

```
\makeatletter
\def\defcmd#1{%
  \ifx\csname#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\expandafter\def\csname}{\def#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

In the case of `\def\str{foo}` we have

```
\ifx\csname\str
```

which is false, so what remains is

```
\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{\expandafter\def\csname}{\def\str}{foo}
```

which becomes (the expansion of `\fi` is empty)

```
\@secondoftwo{\expandafter\def\csname}{\def\str}{foo}
```

and finally

```
\def\str{foo}
```

In the case of `\defcmd\csname str\endcsname{foo}` we'd have

```
\ifx\csname\csname\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{\expandafter\def\csname}{\def\csname}str\endcsname{foo}
```

and, since the test is true,

```
\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{\expandafter\def\csname}{\def\csname}str\endcsname{foo}
```

The expansion of `\else` is empty and gets rid of everything up to the matching `\fi`, so we are left with

```
\@firstoftwo{\expandafter\def\csname}{\def\csname}str\endcsname{foo}
```

and finally

```
\expandafter\def\csname str\endcsname{foo}
```

which is what wee need.

---

"Skipping tokens" in a conditional is performed differently when the condition is true or false: `\iftrue X\else Y\fi` leaves `X\else Y\fi` and it will be the expansion of `\else` that gets rid of `Y`; conversely, `\iffalse X\else Y\fi` will leave `Y\fi`, skipping tokens up to and including `\else`. The expansion of `\fi` is empty, but until it's not expanded it remains in the input stream.

Here I used `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` to be any conditional construction that returns true or false, respectively; `X` and `Y` represent any token list.

Comment: Wow, that's some insight in how LaTeX works. Didn't know a lot of stuff you mentioned. Thanks again egreg `:)`.

Answer (score 9):

```
\def\defcmd#1{%
  \ifx\csname#1%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\csname
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}

\defcmd\str{String}

\show\str

\defcmd\csname str\endcsname{String2}


\show\str

\bye
```

Two classic sins: forgetting to have enough `\expandafter` and forgetting `%` at ends of lines:-)

---

If you replace the definition with your original, the `\show` will show

```
 tex foo
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)
(./foo.tex
> \str=macro:
 \fi ->String.
l.23 \show\str

? 
> \str=macro:
->String2.
l.28 \show\str
```

So the second call actually worked as intended but the first defined `\str` as if you had done

```
\def\str\fi{....}
```

and it *requires* a `\fi` token to follow its use. That is why you get an error if you try to use the defined token later.