# How to display command name and its value

Tags: macros, expansion

Latex displays the command values by default - I am finding it more difficult to display the command names along with the values.

I have a list of commands that I would like to loop over and print each one's name and value.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  % defines foreach

\begin{document}

\def\one{this is one}
\def\two{this is two}
\def\three{this is three}

\def\CMDs{\one,\two,\three}  % list of commands I would like to loop over

\foreach \cmd in \CMDs
{
    \string\cmd = \cmd \\ % should be name = value
}

\end{document}
```

But the `\string` is not resolving the \cmd, its just printing cmd.

Even tried `\expandafter\string\csname\cmd\endcsname = \cmd` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64496/print-name-of-command-defined-by-csname) - no use, it is expanding and printing the value on both sides, not the name.

Please advice on how to achieve this.

In case one would like to know the background, this is for my [CVMaker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cvmaker/) project - to keep track of internal variables and dump their values on demand, as debug-aid for the package users.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are lucky that `\cmd` is a macro that contains the target macro,
thus one `\expandafter` solves the problem, it expands `\cmd` and reveals the target macro to `\string`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% to get correct backslash
\usepackage{tikz}  % defines foreach

\begin{document}

\def\one{this is one}
\def\two{this is two}
\def\three{this is three}

\def\CMDs{\one,\two,\three}  % list of commands I would like to loop over

\foreach \cmd in \CMDs
{
    \expandafter\string\cmd = \cmd\par % should be name = value
}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Further remarks:**

- You can inspect a macro definition by `\show`, e.g.:
  After `\show\cmd` TeX stops and shows the meaning on the console:

  ```
  > \cmd=macro:
  ->\one .
  ```
- Another method is `\meaning`. It works similar to `\string`, but instead of the token, it converts the meaning of the token to a string, e.g.:

  ```
  \typeout{\string\cmd=\meaning\cmd}%
  ```

  prints to the console/`.log` file:

  ```
  \cmd=macro:->\one 
  \cmd=macro:->\two 
  \cmd=macro:->\three
  ```
- If `\cmd` would be have assigned via `\let`, e.g.:

  ```
  \let\cmd=\one
  ```

  then `\cmd` has the same `\meaning` as `\one`. And the name `\one` cannot be derived from `\cmd` anymore.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks for the detailed explanation and quick reply.

Comment: And what if I want to print the value of `\dimen0` when I make before: `\settowidth{\dimen0}{ObJeCt}`?

Comment: @Andrestand: `\the` can be used to get the register values: `\the\dimen0 `.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a flexible implementation where you can choose the mode for showing the command's meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% The user level command just hands its arguments to an inner function
% #1 is optional, default value empty; #2 is the list of commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcommands}{O{}m}
 {
  \gopa_show_commands:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gopa_show_commands:nn #1 #2
 {
  % start a group so changes to the meaning of functions
  % deriving from the key setting will be undone at the end
  \group_begin:
  % evaluate the first argument, which should be `mode=<value>'
  \keys_set:nn { gopa/commands } { #1 }
  % for each item in the second argument (represented by ##1)
  % execute the code below
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    {\ttfamily \token_to_str:N ##1~=~\gopa_show_mode:N ##1 }
    \par
   }
  \group_end:
 }

% a variant for `mode=expand'; \use:n just uses its argument
% so \use:V will expand the control sequence that follows it
% and brace the expansion, so \use:n will remove the braces
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \use:n { V }

% Set up the key/value pairs; just one key that can receive
% the values "show", "expand" or "meaning"; default is "expand"
\keys_define:nn { gopa/commands }
 {
  mode .choice:,
  mode / show    .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \gopa_show_mode:N \cs_show:N,
  mode / expand  .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \gopa_show_mode:N \use:V,
  mode / meaning .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \gopa_show_mode:N \cs_meaning:N,
  mode .initial:n = expand,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\one{this is one}
\def\two{this is two}
\def\three{this is three}

\showcommands{\one,\two,\three}

\showcommands[mode=meaning]{\one,\mbox}

\end{document}
```

Another possible choice is `mode=show` that will use the terminal for showing the command's meaning. Use `mode=meaning` when one of the commands in the list is not a parameterless macro.

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. Its working fine and looking tidy and nice. I should start looking into the Latex 3 - seems it is powerful (and complex).

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem: LaTeX3 is not that complex like it looks. I just started using it. egreg recommended to read expl3.pdf (type `texdoc expl3` in your terminal). That document give a short overview about the new syntax and some more. All (?) new command are described in interface3.pdf (`texdoc interface3`).

Comment: @Tobi: Thanks Tobi - thats helpful information. Will certainly look into the `texdoc expl3`