# Gobble every occurrence of \mypath../

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is there a neat way to remove all instances of the text `\mypath../` from the input, using TeX's text processing capabilities? The `ifthen` approach below works, but seems to be a bit heavyweight. Also, I'm looking for a solution that would work **before** the `\documentclass` command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\mypath}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1#2#3}{../}}{}{#1#2#3}%
}

\begin{document}
  Gobble: \mypath../

  Don't gobble: \mypath.ab
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an expandable way:

```
\long\def\mypath#1#2#3{\mypathaux../#1#2#3../}
\long\def\mypathaux../#1../{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\mypathgobble
  \else
    #1
  \fi}
\long\def\mypathgobble#1#2#3{}
```

The macro `\mypath` absorbes the next three tokens and calls `\mypathaux` in a curious way; let's see the two main cases:

1. `\mypath../` becomes `\mypathaux../../../`
2. `\mypath xyz` becomes `\mypathaux../xyz../`

The macro `\mypathaux` has only *one* argument, all tokens that go from the first occurrence of `../` to the second occurrence. In case 1 there's nothing between the two occurrences, so `#1` is empty. In case 2, `#1` is `xyz`.

The macro now tests whether `#1` is empty (it's a slick trick by H. Oberdiek); if it is, it calls `\mypathgobble` that swallows the `../` that remain on the main token list; otherwise it just returns `#1`.

A similar way that gets rid also of the `\fi` after `#1`, which might be needed in some situations is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mypath[3]{\@mypath../#1#2#3../}
\long\def\@mypath../#1../{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi\@gobblethree{#1}}
\providecommand\@gobblethree[3]{}
\makeatother
```

This uses features from the LaTeX kernel, while the former macros don't.

Let's see the two cases. With `\mypath xyz` we get

```
\@mypath../xyz../
```

and the test returns false, so we're left with

```
\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi\@gobblethree{xyz}
```

where `\expandafter` acts on `\fi` (it simply disappears), leaving

```
\@secondoftwo\@gobblethree{xyz}
```

so `\@secondoftwo` finally produces `xyz`. In the case of `\mypath../` we get

```
\@mypath../../../
```

and the test returns true; this leaves

```
\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi\@gobblethree{}../
```

(only the first two `../` disappear as part of the pattern matching). The first `\expandafter` acts on `\else` which causes everything up to the matching `\fi` to disappear:

```
\@firstoftwo\@gobblethree{}../
```

and now we get

```
\@gobblethree../
```

which leaves nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. Still, I wonder what happens to the third `../` in `\mypath../`--> `\@mypath../../../` after it has been matched to `\@mypath../../` with `#1` empty.

Comment: @user946850 In the case you mention, the first pair of `../` disappears as part of the action of `\@mypath` and the third because `\@gobblethree` is called. I'll add something.

Comment: That makes it perfectly clear. Here's the link to the question/answer that explains `\expandafter`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/8057