# having problems using arrayjobx with tikz - how can i use arrays in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, loops

I need the help of some smart people ;)

I want to draw a picture with TikZ, which is heavily based on randomization and I want to make it quite parametrized.
It's actually a graph of n nodes where edges are incident to nodes based on previous node placement, so one can *not* do it all in only one for-loop, that's not possible (and i need x- and y-coordinates independently).
In my plans i store x- and y-coordinates in an array and retrieve the data later for calculations. but I run into problems....

Array usage in TikZ is either limited or badly described (how to store/change data *after* initialization?)
So I use the package [`arrayjobx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx). below is a minimal non-working example (from my memory, unfortunately, my coding PC is currently not accessible; but I hope you see the problem without having a 100%-guaranteed compilable example):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newarray\xcoord
\def \n {5}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  {
  % roll randomvalues and store them in arrays xcoord
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{rnd*10}
  \xcoord(\i)={\xe}

  \foreach \j in {1,...,\i}
  {
    % access data in second nested loop; accessing is done with \checkArrayname and \cachedata to avoid parsing errors
    \checkxcoord(\j)
    \let\xf\cachedata
    % next line is just for "debugging"
    \node[draw,circle] at (\i,\j) {\xf};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can access the data without problems in the first loop. It's working fine. But in the second nested loop, no matter what value `\j` should have, `\xf` gets the value of `\xcoord(\i)`, instead of `\xcoord(\j)`. I tried it in different ways, using a counter for `\j`, using length-parameters instead of `\let`, etc. but the result is always the same.

What could cause this behaviour? Does anyone of you know a workaround?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assignment such as

```
\xcoord{\i}={\xe}
```

usually loads `\xcoord` with the *macro* `\xe`, not its value (which can change).

If you want to load it with the value of `\xe`, then say

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newarray\xcoord
\expandarrayelementtrue
\def \n {5}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  {
  % roll randomvalues and store them in arrays xcoord
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{rnd*10}
  \xcoord(\i)={\xe}
[...]
```

The change to the conditional `\ifexpandarrayelement` will be confined to this `tikzpicture` (the environment forms a group). If you have other `arrayjobx` assignments in the environment that mustn't obey to this setting, then put `\expandarrayelementtrue` inside the `\foreach` or say `\expandarrayelementfalse` when you need not to expand.

Comment: hi, many thanks, that solved my problem! (i had plenty of others afterwards, one strikingly similar...)

Comment: however, though i understood now the difference between value and macro, i don't have an idea when and how to use \expand commands. i'd like to know more, it seems to be key knowledge for me to improve my tikzing capabilities!
i tried searching for some explanations with google, but i probably used the wrong keywords, can you give me hint in that matter? latex + expand/expansion/noexpand did not really come up with something....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the result of `\xe` is not expanded .

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,arrayjobx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newarray\xcoord
\def \n {5}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  {
  % roll randomvalues and store them in arrays xcoord
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{rnd*10}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\xcoord(\noexpand\i)={\xe}}\temp

  \foreach \j in {1,...,\i}
  {
    \node[draw,circle] at (2*\i,2*\j) {\xcoord(\j)};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think i had the same problem with a counter (but i am not sure; i solved it by exchanging the counters by 1-element arrays :D)
can i use the same method for counters? i mean, the \edef\temp\noexpand.... monster?
or do i need a different kind of command if i want a counter to survive correctly through various loops?

Comment: @dps_kane Usually `\the\countername` is enough but we need to have an example to be sure. Expansion in TeX is crucial for assignment and you can search for `\expandafter` on this site or get the famous *TeX by Topic* and go nuts. Here is a good overview http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter