# I want \edef to work

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, counters, graphs, calculations

I want to generate a list called `anglelist` to generate a graph...
the prefered command for me is `\edef\anglelist{\fullanglelist}` but gives me an error.

But using `\edef\anglelist{\fullanglelist}` and `\edef\anglelist{\fixedlist}` wont give me any error.

> My Question is "Would you tell me how should I make `\edef\anglelist{\fullanglelist}` working?

Thanks, in advance. Following please have a look at the code I am talking about.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcount\nodes
\nodes=8

\newcount\hnodes
\hnodes=\nodes
\advance \hnodes by -1
\divide \hnodes by 2
%
\newcount\hnodesplus
\hnodesplus=\nodes
\advance \hnodesplus by 1
\divide \hnodesplus by 2
%
\newcount\initialstepsize
\initialstepsize=360
\divide \initialstepsize by \nodes
%
\newcount\initialremainder
\initialremainder=\initialstepsize
\multiply \initialremainder by -\nodes
\advance \initialremainder by 360
%
\newcount\hstep
\hstep=\initialstepsize
\divide \hstep by 2

\newcount\simplestep
\simplestep=\initialstepsize
\ifnum \initialremainder > 0%this makes angles a larger than expected. 
\advance \simplestep by 1
\fi



\def\fullanglelister{%
\newcount\tempa
\newcount\tempb
\tempa=0
\tempb=0
%
\loop
\the\tempa\relax
\advance\tempa by \initialstepsize
\advance\tempb by \initialremainder
\ifnum\tempb > \hnodes% usually chosen to be 0, (better to be) \hnodes, or \nodes 
\advance\tempa by 1
\advance\tempb by -\nodes
\fi
\ifnum \tempa < 360
,
\repeat}


\def\shortanglelister{0, \the\simplestep, ..., 359}
\def\fixedlist{0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315}

\edef\anglelist{\shortanglelister}
%\edef\anglelist{\fullanglelister} % this one doesn't work!
%\edef\anglelist{\fixedlist} % but this works!

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \angle in \anglelist
\node[rectangle,draw=black!50] (\angle) at (\angle:2) {\angle};

\foreach \from in \anglelist
\foreach \to in \anglelist
\path (\from) edge [->,bend right=\the\hstep,looseness=0.8] (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}


\fullanglelister
\shortanglelister
\fixedlist

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've got a rather haphazard mix here of low level TeX primitive programming and TikZ! In particular, have you read up on expansion, for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter/519? You _cannot_ perform assignments inside `\edef`.

Comment: Apart from the mistake of having `\newcount\tempa` and `\newcount\tempb` in the definition of `\fullanglelister`, you have to take into account that `\edef` only *expands* macros, but does no assignment.

Comment: @JosephWright Re: "You cannot perform assignments inside `\edef`" ...unless you use tricks like `\unexpanded` or `\expandonce`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, in TeX you _cannot_ perform assignments inside `\edef` or similar contexts. In LuaTeX things inside `\directlua` are different, and one  might appeal to `\csname` ... `\endcnsame` making undefined control sequences into `\relax` for 'special effects', but that is not general.

Comment: You can use `\foreach\x in {0,45,...,359}` to get same list you are preparing with `\fullanglelister`; it's not clear why going the hard way for writing the full list.

Comment: clearly you can not use that command in an edef as it does not work by expansion, perhaps you should edit the question asking about what you actually want to do rather than about one possible way of doing it which can not work. Also you should not have `\newcount` inside the definition of `\fullanglelister` as you do not want to allocate new registers every time you use the command.

Comment: `\usepackage{xinttools}\edef\x{\xintListWithSep{, }{\xintSeq[45]{0}{359}}}`

Comment: `\usepackage{xintexpr}\edef\mylist{\xinttheexpr 0..[45]..359\relax}`

Answer (score 5):

If (for some reason) you want to expand the loop in an edef then you need to write it using expansion, not using assignments. The following code expands to

```
0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315
```

as shown by the typeout line

```
B: 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315
```

on the console

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcount\nodes
\nodes=8

\newcount\hnodes
\hnodes=\nodes
\advance \hnodes by -1
\divide \hnodes by 2
%
\newcount\hnodesplus
\hnodesplus=\nodes
\advance \hnodesplus by 1
\divide \hnodesplus by 2
%
\newcount\initialstepsize
\initialstepsize=360
\divide \initialstepsize by \nodes
%
\newcount\initialremainder
\initialremainder=\initialstepsize
\multiply \initialremainder by -\nodes
\advance \initialremainder by 360
%
\newcount\hstep
\hstep=\initialstepsize
\divide \hstep by 2

\newcount\simplestep
\simplestep=\initialstepsize
\ifnum \initialremainder > 0%this makes angles a larger than expected. 
\advance \simplestep by 1
\fi



\makeatletter
\def\fullanglelister{%
\expandafter\@gobble\romannumeral`\^^@%
\expandafter\zz\shortanglelister\relax}
\def\zz#1,#2,#3,#4\relax{%
\ifnum#1<\numexpr#4\relax
, \the\numexpr#1\relax
\expandafter\zz\the\numexpr#1+#2\relax,#2,#3,#4\relax
\fi}
\makeatother

\def\shortanglelister{0, \the\simplestep, ..., 359}
\def\fixedlist{0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315}

\edef\anglelist{\shortanglelister}
\typeout{A:\anglelist}
\edef\anglelist{\fullanglelister} % this one does work!
\typeout{B:\anglelist}
%\edef\anglelist{\fixedlist} % but this works!

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \angle in \anglelist
\node[rectangle,draw=black!50] (\angle) at (\angle:2) {\angle};

\foreach \from in \anglelist
\foreach \to in \anglelist
\path (\from) edge [->,bend right=\the\hstep,looseness=0.8] (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}


\fullanglelister
\shortanglelister
\fixedlist

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want integers to move toward a particular goal as evenly as possible, the best way is to recompute the step size at each iteration as the remaining distance divided by the number of remaining steps.

The usual practice is to place the result of `\edef` into a different macro than the one creating it.  For example, the output of `\pgfmathparse` is put into `\pgfmathresult`, and `\pgfmathsetmacro` accepts the output macro name as an argument.  This is the approach I took.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcount\nodes% considering how infrequently this is used, a macro would suffice

\def\fullanglelister#1{% #1 = output macro name (global)
\bgroup% use local registers
  \count1=0 % angle
  \count2=\nodes% remaining steps
  \edef\temp{\the\count1}% output macro (local)
  \loop
    \count3=360 % compute step size (360-angle)/steps
    \advance \count3 by -\count1
    \divide \count3 by \count2
    \advance\count1 by \count3
    \advance\count2 by -1
    \edef\temp{\temp,\the\count1}%
  \ifnum \count2>1 \repeat
  \global\let#1\temp
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\nodes=8
\fullanglelister{\anglelist}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hstep}{360/\nodes}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \angle in \anglelist
\node[rectangle,draw=black!50] (\angle) at (\angle:2) {\angle};

\foreach \from in \anglelist {
  \foreach \to in \anglelist {
    \path (\from) edge [->,bend right=\hstep,looseness=0.8] (\to);}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]