# Define a variable using a local parameter e.g. \thechapter, and use it everywhere

Tags: macros

I'm doing

```
\chapter{chap_one} \newcommand{\chap_oneChapter}{\thechapter}
bla bla bla
\chapter{chap_two} \newcommand{\chap_twoChapter}{\thechapter}
\chap_oneChapter and then \chap_twoChapter
```

I expected to have printed

> 1 and then 2

but instead I have

> 2 and then 2

as if every time LaTeX finds a \chap_oneChapter, it assigns the value of \thechapter, which is not what I wanted. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your `\newcommand`s and the use of `\VectorOperatorsChapter` and `\AnotherTopicChapter`. Can you explain?

Comment: @Werner sorry, I edited the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for `\label{..}` and `\ref{..}`?

```
\chapter{chap one vector operators} \label{chap:VectorOperators}
bla bla bla
\chapter{chap two another topic} \label{chap:AnotherTopic}
\ref{chap:VectorOperators} and then \ref{chap:AnotherTopic}
```

---

In any case, if that's not what you are looking for…

Roughly you have to expand it, `\edef` for instance. Note that you can't have `_` in the name of commands.

```
\chapter{chap one vector operators} \edef\VectorOperatorsChapter{\thechapter}
bla bla bla
\chapter{chap two another topic} \edef\AnotherTopicChapter{\thechapter}
\VectorOperatorsChapter{} and then \AnotherTopicChapter
```

This might give problems at some point, you would need `\protected@edef` to be secure. So you might want to define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\savevalue[2]{\protected@edef#1{#2}}
\makeatletter
```

and then use like `\savevalue\AnotherTopicChapter{\thechapter}`.

Comment: What is the difference between \def and \edef? And no, \label and \ref are not what I'm looking for, actually I'll use this variables I'm trying to define inside some sort of \ref.

Comment: @BrunoMurino -- Maybe you want to look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519/8528 (there's actually a few good `\edef` questions on this site).

Comment: @BrunoMurino `\edef` expands its contents at the moment of definition. If you defined with `\def` (or `\newcommand`) the only thing you are storing is the symbolic `\thechapter` so it expands to its value later rather than at the point of definition. In any case, you can still label de chapter and do `\def\VectorOperatorsChapter{\ref{chap:VectorOperators}}` and use `\VectorOperatorsChapter` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks! Everything is working fine now! And thanks for the explanation!