# LaTeX newcommand limitation

Tags: macros, latex-base

I want to know the possibilities and the limitation of LaTeX's `\newcommand` regarding the definition and the use/call of new macros. I know some of these examples are primitive but they can help to understand the limitations.
I am only interested in basic `\newcommand`s with "\"char+ as name.

Invalid examples:

```
\newcommand{\newcenter}{center} 
\begin{\newcenter}
\end{center}

\newcommand{\tabularthree}{{tabular}}
\begin \tabularthree {ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabularthree

\newcommand{\tion}{tion}
\sec\tion{mysec}
```

Valid examples:

```
\newcommand{\optarg}{[myoptarg]} 
\section\optarg{mysec}

\newcommand{\cc}{cc}
\newcommand{\mybegin}{\begin}
\mybegin{tabular}{c\cc}
cell& cell
\end{tabular}

\newcommand{\tabulartwo}{tabular}
\begin{\tabulartwo} {ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabulartwo

\newcommand{\tabularfour}{tabular}
\begin \tabularfour{ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabularfour
```

Comment: I don't really see what the use-case would be other than unreadable and unmaintainable document source code.

Comment: These don't so much look like limitations of `\newcommand` but an issue of understanding LaTeX (and TeX)'s command expansion rules.

Comment: these are not really related to `\newcommand`  but to the _use_ of the macros, you would get the same errors if the macros were defined by the primitive `\def`

Answer (score 13):

Henri Menke told you how to work around the rules. This answer will show you why the syntax you used (doesn't) work.

#### The ones that don't work:

```
\newcommand{\newcenter}{center}
\begin{\newcenter}
\end{center}
```

This one fails because `\@currenvir` expands to `\newcenter` and when LaTeX calls the `\@checkend` command, it compares the meaning of `\@currenvir` and the argument to `\end`, which is `center`. The comparison fails because it compares `\newcenter` with `center` without further expasion, so they differ and an error is raised. The error message, on the other hand, fully expands `\@currenvir` and the error message is misleading:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 29 ended by \end{center}.
```

---

```
\newcommand{\tabularthree}{{tabular}}
\begin \tabularthree {ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabularthree
```

This one fails because LaTeX checks if the enfironment exists with `\ifcsname` which will build a command with the argument to `\begin` which, in this case, is `\tabularthree`, which expands to `{tabular}`. The `\ifcsname` then checks for a command named `{tabular}`, which doesn't exist and LaTeX tells you:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment {tabular} undefined.
```

---

```
\newcommand{\tion}{tion}
\sec\tion{mysec}
```

This one fails because it's invalid. The command `\sec` is expanded, and it is the secant function, which is only allowed in math-mode, so TeX thinks you forgot a `$`:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.46 \sec
```

If `\sec` wasn't a math-mode command, TeX would try to execute it. If it had an argument, the argument would be the command `\tion`, which then expands to `tion` and then the `\sec` command would do its thing (whatever it happened to be) with `tion`. If it didn't exist, TeX would complain that `\sec` doesn't exist.

---

#### The one that [works](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=46713663#46713663):

```
\newcommand{\optarg}{[myoptarg]}
\section\optarg{mysec}
```

This one *compiles*, but it doesn't produce what you'd expect. The test for the optional argument fails, because the code for `\section` doesn't see a `[` character (and it doesn't expand `\optarg` looking for it), so it takes `\optarg` as the mandatory argument and the title of the section becomes **`[myoptarg]`** and `mysec` is written below.

---

#### The ones that *do* work:

```
\newcommand{\cc}{cc}
\newcommand{\mybegin}{\begin}
\mybegin{tabular}{c\cc}
cell& cell
\end{tabular}
```

This one works because when TeX expands `\mybegin` it just finds `\begin`. TeX then proceeds expanding `\begin` and doing things normally. The `\cc` thing works because `tabular` expands the tokens of the alignment preamble.

---

```
\newcommand{\tabulartwo}{tabular}
\begin{\tabulartwo} {ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabulartwo
```

This one works by the same reason that the first case didn't. The check for the environment name is performed for `\tabulartwo` and `\tabulartwo`, which are the same thing. And the braces there don't make a difference because by TeX's argument grabbing rules, a normal argument is either a single token (`\tabulartwo` is a single token) or, if a open brace (`{`) is found, then the argument is the `<balanced text>` within that pair of braces (`\tabulartwo` and `tabular` are `<balanced text>` within a pair of braces).

---

```
\newcommand{\tabularfour}{tabular}
\begin \tabularfour{ccc}
cell& cell
\end \tabularfour
```

Same as above.

---

But you *really* shouldn't be inventing syntax for commands, because even if it works, you will obfuscate your code and not even you will understand it in a few weeks.

Comment: On the other hand, `\begin{tabular}{c\cc}` will not work if the `array` package is loaded.

Answer (score 10):

`\expandafter` solves almost all your problems.  You seem to be a LaTeX beginner, so these are not things you should usually have to do.  Please also have a look at [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\newcenter}{center} 
\expandafter\begin\expandafter{\newcenter}
\end{center}

\newcommand{\tabularthree}{{tabular}}
\expandafter\begin\tabularthree{ccc}
cell& cell
\expandafter\end\tabularthree

\newcommand{\tion}{tion}
\csname sec\tion\endcsname{mysec}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch.  Your answer is almost verbatim my answer.  lol.