# \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption} not working

Tags: documentclass-writing

I get an error which I don't understand. I have the following cls-file called error.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}                                            
\ProvidesClass{error}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}  
\ProcessOptions\relax
% 
\LoadClass{scrartcl} 
\endinput
```

So e.g. if I start my LaTeX-file with

```
\documentclass[titlepage=true]{error}
```

then I should get a separate titlepage. But unfortunately, the compiling process stops calling `/usr/local/texlive/2021/.../koma-script/tocbasic.sty`

Here my TeX-File I am using:

```
% ------------------
%\documentclass[titlepage=true]{error} % not working
% Compiling stops with 
% /usr/local/texlive/2021/.../koma-script/tocbasic.sty
% ------------------
\documentclass{error}   
% working with \LoadClass[titlepage=true]{scrartcl} or 
% \LoadClass{scrartcl}in the error.cls file
% ------------------
\begin{document}
%
\subject{-- \LaTeX --} 
\title{--Titel--}
\subtitle{--Untertitel--}
\date{\today} 
\maketitle
\section{Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{error}
\DeclareOption*{\expandafter\PassOptionsToClass\expandafter{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%
\LoadClass{scrartcl}
\endinput
```

Comment: More on the usage of \expandafter and examples can be found in the TeX-book or do you have other references?

Comment: @Ulrich There are many posts here. For instance [When to use `\edef`, `\noexpand` and `\expandafter`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/)

Comment: Nice, worked for me too. But why is this needed now? it worked until the update from 01.06.2021??

Comment: @Cube, the same happens with me and I was therefore surprised. Also in the book of Goosens et all there is no hint why. Would be nice to learn "why".

Comment: @egrep: I found a rather interesting and detailed explanation of `\expandafter` by Bechtolsheim in [link](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf)

Comment: @Ulrich: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/580

Comment: I just updated my system and now it works "correctly", i.e. without the `\expandafter`