# Expand two counters in collect package

Tags: counters, expansion, answers, collect

I write a command to store the problem answer with the collect package.
Mr @egreg help me expand the problem number in the aux file. Now I meet another trouble with the answer. When the answer contains a counter, it will not expand.
Please help me correct the below code.

[image]

Moreover, please give some documentation of "expandafter" and ".aux" commands
Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{btcol}
\newcounter{cbt} %the number problems
\newcounter{anschoice} %the answer key

\newenvironment{bt}
 {\refstepcounter{cbt}\par
  \noindent{\bfseries Problem \thecbt}.}{}
  
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{%
  \@bsphack\expandafter\loigiai@aux\expandafter{\expanded{\thecbt}}{#1}\@esphack
}
\newcommand{\loigiai@aux}[2]{%
  \begin{collect}{btcol}{\par\noindent {\bfseries AP #1}.\ignorespaces}{}{}{} 
#2%
  \end{collect}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{anschoice}{3}
\begin{bt}
Content 1
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.1 $ \rightarrow $ Choice: \Alph{anschoice}}
\end{bt}

\begin{bt}
Content 2 
\end{bt}

\setcounter{anschoice}{2}
\begin{bt}
Content 3
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.3  $ \rightarrow $ Choice: \Alph{anschoice}}
\end{bt}

\includecollection{btcol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of setting the counter? Can't you just say `Choice: B` in the second case?

Comment: @egreg It is a answer case for multichoice question.

Comment: @egreg I am a newbie. So sorry when I do not know that the question can update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this could be better automated, but here, I expand the offending phrase with an `\edef`, before passing it to `\loigiai`.

EDITED to simplify input for the user.  Instead of forcing an `\edef` upon the user, I create the macro `\exloigiai` which the user may alternatively use, which applies `\expanded` to the argument prior to passing it to `\loigiai`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{btcol}
\newcounter{cbt} %the number problems
\newcounter{anschoice} %the answer key

\newenvironment{bt}
 {\refstepcounter{cbt}\par
  \noindent{\bfseries Problem \thecbt}.}{}
  
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{%
  \@bsphack\expandafter\loigiai@aux\expandafter{\expanded{\thecbt}}{#1}\@esphack
}
\newcommand{\loigiai@aux}[2]{%
  \begin{collect}{btcol}{\par\noindent {\bfseries AP #1}.\ignorespaces}{}{}{} 
#2%
  \end{collect}
}

\newcommand\exloigiai[1]{\expandafter\loigiai\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{anschoice}{3}
\begin{bt}
Content 1
\exloigiai{Answer for Pro.1 $ \rightarrow $ Choice: \Alph{anschoice}}
\end{bt}

\begin{bt}
Content 2 
\end{bt}

\setcounter{anschoice}{2}
\begin{bt}
Content 3
\exloigiai{Answer for Pro.3 $ \rightarrow $ Choice: \Alph{anschoice}}
\end{bt}

\includecollection{btcol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think it will make difficult for beginners.

Comment: @NamTranLe The alternative is to place the expansion into the `\loigiai` definition.  But that is only if you can guarantee that all of its arguments are always expandable.

Comment: @NamTranLe I have edited my answer to provided an alternative macro, `\exloigiai`, to be used in lieu of `\loigiai`, when the user wants the argument expanded.

Comment: B.Segleyes. Thank you very much. it very usefull!

Comment: Can you give me some document about these command sir?

Comment: @NamTranLe Primarily, I would just search this site on which we post.  However, if I could pull a reference out, it might be https://www.texdev.net/2018/12/06/a-new-primitive-expanded, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter, and https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!