# Referencing all uses of a multiply defined label

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to be able to apply the same label multiple times and have a referencing command, that lists all uses of that label. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{example}

\begin{document}

Warning: Examples
\myref{pessimistic} % 1, 4
are passimistic. Apart from that, only examples
\myref{beginner} % 1, 2
are suitable for beginners.

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{beginner} \mylabel{pessimistic}

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{beginner} \mylabel{optimistic}

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{intermediate} 

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{expert} \mylabel{pessimistic}

\end{document}
```

I'm looking for an implementation for `pdflatex` - avoiding `makeindex` if possible.

Is there already a package that does something similar - or how could I go about implementing that?

Comment: An `index` seems the natural way to do this- just out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid using one?

Comment: @cmhughes I agree and I'm kinda tempted to (ab)use the indexing mechanisms to do the above. This is for a book project, in which the first `\part` is introducing topics. At the end of each topic, I want to give a list of references, where this topic appears in the rest of the book. In that way, it's similar to the TeX's back-references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Taken from latex.ltx
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    {\expandafter\xdef\csname rr@#2\endcsname{\@firstoftwo #3}}
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}
     \expandafter\xdef\csname rr@#2\endcsname{\csname rr@#2\endcsname, \@firstoftwo #3}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
\newcounter{example}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\csname rr@#1\endcsname}
\let\mylabel\label
\begin{document}

Warning:

Examples
\myref{pessimistic} % 1, 4
are pessimistic.

Apart from that, only examples
\myref{beginner} % 1, 2
are suitable for beginners.

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{beginner} \mylabel{pessimistic}

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{beginner} \mylabel{optimistic}

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{intermediate} 

\refstepcounter{example} \mylabel{expert} \mylabel{pessimistic}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\@newl@bel` is taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) and updated to create a macro `\rr@<label>` for every `\label{<label>}`. If `\rr@<label>` already exists, then it appends the new label, otherwise it just creates it. Referencing requires `\myref`, while `\mylabel` is similar to `\label`.

This will not work with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

---

Label can also be supplied as a comma-separated list using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and the following definition of `\mylabel`. See [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764) for more options:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{% \mylabel{<list of labels>}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\label{##1}}% How to process each item
  \docsvlist{#1}}% Process list of items
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there by any chance a way to extend this to parsing `\mylabel{beginner, pessimistic}` as `\mylabel{beginner} \mylabel{pessimistic}` ?

Comment: @arney: I've update the definition of `\mylabel` to process it as such.