# Beamer and a for each loop

Tags: beamer, loops, comma-separated-list

I'm using the `beamer` presentation package and trying to combine the examples from this post [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list) with the `beamer` package.

In modifying the top example, chaning

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeenumerate}{ m }
 {
  \begin{frame}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \frame \fbox{##1} }
  \end{frame}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeenumerate{a, b ,c, d, ,e }

\end{document}
```

I want to have a b c d and e all in separate beamer frames. I'm not sure how to get this to work, and which method of iterating over a comma separated list is best to use i've tried them all and none work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One issue you currently have is trying to create a `\frame` inside another `frame`. Moreover, `\frame` takes an argument, which you're not supplying in a proper way.

Here is [the `etoolbox` implementation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159170/5764) that inserts each item in the list on a separate `frame`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\makeenumerate[1]{%
  \forcsvlist{\makeenumerate@item}{#1}
}
\newcommand\makeenumerate@item[1]{%
  \begin{frame}
    \fbox{\Huge #1}
  \end{frame}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeenumerate{a, b ,c, d, ,e }

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks i fixed the example but this seems to work great