# How can I change the default \\ spacing?

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-spacing, letters

So, I have a definition which takes in data like this:

```
...{apple\\orange\\cat\\imperial green tea\\left-handed president}...
```

In the document I get the following after compilation:

apple

orange

cat

imperial green tea

left-handed president

---

However, the line spacing is too large for my taste. I'd like to adjust it to be a bit smaller. How can I do this?

Comment: If you change your input, it may help to look at [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764)

Comment: Shouldn't this be formatted as a list or something?

Comment: Depending on your usage, the `stackengine` package could help.  See http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 1):

Try the package [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

text\\at\\normal\\spacing

\begin{spacing}{.8}
apple\\orange\\cat\\imperial green tea\\left-handed president
\end{spacing}

text\\at\\normal\\spacing

\end{document}
```

Changing the `.8` to `1` gives single-spaced lines, `2` gives double-spaced lines, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your particular use case,  you might want to consider using a list type structure, which allows you to

1. Remove the vertical spacing:

   [image]
2. Have some vertical spacing:

   [image]
3. And also number the items if desired:

   [image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\MyList}{apple, orange, cat, imperial green tea, left-handed president}

\begin{document}

You can have them listed:
\medskip
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, label={}, leftmargin=0pt]
    \foreach \x in \MyList {\item \x}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
Or you can have them numbered, and adjust the vertical spacing:
\medskip
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, label={}, leftmargin=0pt, itemsep=5pt]
    \foreach \x in \MyList {\item \x}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
Or you can have them numbered:
\medskip
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,itemsep=5pt]
    \foreach \x in \MyList {\item \x}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```