# Auto generate list-items within table from string with delimiter

Tags: tables, lists, etoolbox, csvsimple

This is a follow-up on this question: [Creating bullet-list from string with delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196078/creating-bullet-list-from-string-with-delimiters)

I have a CSV file where I genereate some tables from. Some of those table cells will have items that should be itemized.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareListParser{\ListParser}{|}
\newcommand{\listItems}[1]{
    \parbox{10cm}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \newcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[] ##1}
            \expandafter\ListParser\expandafter{#1}
            \ListParser{#1}
        \end{itemize}
    }
}
\begin{document}
  \csvreader[head to column names]{content/usecases.csv}{}{%
    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Name     & \ucname \\ \hline
        Trigger  & \listItems{\trigger} \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  }
\end{document}
```

CSV Example:

```
ucname,trigger
test,This is|A test
test2,Barely
test3,No List
test4,List|Again|Here
```

However, this current code gives me the output of the whole string of `\trigger` twice, and not delimited.

Answer (score 4):

You need to expand the list you process twice and only process the list once:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{usecases.csv}
ucname,trigger
test,This is|A test
test2,Barely
test3,No List
test4,List|Again|Here
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareListParser{\ListParser}{|}
\newcommand{\listItems}[1]{%
  \parbox{10cm}{%
    \begin{itemize}%
      \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\item[] ##1}
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ListParser\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1}
    \end{itemize}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[head to column names]{usecases.csv}{}{%
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      Name     & \ucname \\ \hline
      Trigger  & \listItems{\trigger} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Why didn't you get bullet points in your itemize list?

Comment: @Andrew: The OP uses `\item[]` which nullifies the bullet.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I realised this when I was getting a coffee... Clearly needed it:)

Comment: Hmm, I can't really get it to work properly.. If I type exactly what you posted I get this error: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }`.. Adding back in `\ListParser{#1}` makes it compile and spit it out both right and wrong at the same time.. (Both the separated string and the complete string as separate bulletpoints)

Comment: @FrederikNielsen: First of all, you only need one `\ListParser` command. You probably have two. Make sure that this is the case. I see two in your code snippet in the post.

Comment: @Werner - I have tried the exact code in your answer, and that gives the error above

Comment: @FrederikNielsen: I've added my full code to the answer, which includes the use of [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) for portability. If that doesn't compile for you, then clear all your auxiliary files and try again. If that doesn't work, include `\listfiles` in your preamble and report back on the file list displayed in your `.log` - you may have outdated versions of packages.

Comment: @Werner - File list: http://pastebin.com/uq1Hiyke - It works with the exact example you give, but it does not work when passing through my own CSV file. I get these two errors before it starts going crazy: `Missing character: There is no ø in font cmr10!` and `Missing character: There is no å in font cmr10!`

Comment: @Werner - Seems like I found the issue. The issue is there when the CSV entry is empty. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: @FrederikNielsen: I don't know what you mean when you say "CSV entry".

Comment: @Werner - by "CSV Entry" i mean a line in the CSV file like `test,This is|A test` and `test22,` where it is the last one that will make this thing fail.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen: Ah. An empty list. This means that you're trying to set an `itemize` without an `\item`, which is the problem. One would need to test whether the list is empty and condition on typesetting an `itemize` based on that. I'll write something up (later).