# Use the counter value as an argument

Tags: macros, environments, counters, environment-variables

Do you know a simple way to use the current counter value to call the argument in a macro?

### In myPackage I have this

Note: I have the for loop defined as

```
% \forloop[step]{counter}{initial_value}{conditional}{code_block}
```

The problem is in the following code

```
\newcounter{foo}

\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]{
    \newcommand{\myLocalMacro}[#1]{% number of arguments depends on the value inserted in myEnvironment (this works fine)
        \forloop[1]{foo}{1}{\numexpr\value{foo}-1<#1}{
            ##\value{foo} % HERE I need to return ##1 if foo is 1, ##2 if foo is 2 etc. (this doesn't work)
            - % some separator
        }%end forloop
    }%end myLocalMacro
}
{}%end myEnvironment
```

I tested the variable number of arguments in `\myLocalMacro` and it works.

I also tested the nesting of arguments in `\forloop` - writing `##1`, `##2` etc. inside the for loop gives 1st and 2nd value. Now I need it dependent on `foo` counter.

### The main document will look like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{myPackage}
\begin{document}

    \begin{myEnvironment}{7}
        \myLocalMacro{F}{O}{O}{B}{A}{R}{1} % this separation into arguments will be written manually
        \myLocalMacro{F}{O}{O}{B}{A}{R}{2}
        \myLocalMacro{F}{O}{O}{B}{A}{R}{3}
    \end{myEnvironment}
    
    or

    \begin{myEnvironment}{3}
        \myLocalMacro{T}{e}{X}
        \myLocalMacro{a}{b}{c}
    \end{myEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

The expected output should look like

> F - O - O - B - A - R - 1 -
>
> F - O - O - B - A - R - 2 -
>
> F - O - O - B - A - R - 3 -
>
> or
>
> T - e - X -
>
> a - b - c -

Well, this is only an example, the real formating will be more complex, which is why I defined an environment for it and don't do it manually for every single character.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you express you goal/application in a few sentences?

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe, this requires to make `#` inactive for the macro definition

Comment: If you are going to iterate over some given list, maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list) would help. By the way, in that case you do not even need to handle the number of arguments.

Comment: It's not clear how you'd use this environment; can you make some examples telling what's the supposed output?

Comment: You don't mean something like `\arabic{foo}` do you?

Comment: @JPi No, I don't want to print the counter in the output file. I need to call the apropriate argument with the counter.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you mean `\#`? But this will print the hashtag, this is not what I need.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík: No, I did not mean `\#` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposed definition can't work, because TeX makes no expansion to the tokens in the replacement text of a macro and `#1` must be *literal*: it can't be given as `#\value{counter}`. There are some tricks for making this possible, but I don't think they would help in your case.

Here's something that might be what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]
 {\let\myEnv@Temp#1\relax}
 {}

\newcommand\myLocalMacro[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\myEnv@Temp\expandafter{\next}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\addhyphen}[1]{#1 - }
\newcommand{\addcomma}[1]{#1, }

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{\addhyphen}
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR1}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR2}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR3}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\begin{myEnvironment}{\addcomma}
\myLocalMacro{TeX}\par
\myLocalMacro{abc}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `myEnvironment` is the formatting macro which is applied to every token in the argument to `\myLocalMacro`.

[image]

A different implementation that doesn't require to define auxiliary macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]
 {\renewcommand\myEnv@Temp[1]{#1}}
 {}

\newcommand\myEnv@Temp{} % initialize

\newcommand\myLocalMacro[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\myEnv@Temp\expandafter{\next}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{#1 - }
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR1}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR2}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR3}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\begin{myEnvironment}{#1, }
\myLocalMacro{TeX}\par
\myLocalMacro{abc}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `myEnvironment` is the formatting you want to apply to each token.

If you want to preserve spaces, you need a more complex approach; here's a straightforward way with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnvironment}{m}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \pavlik_myenv_temp:n { #1 }
 }
 {
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\myLocalMacro{m}
 {
  \pavlik_myenv_local:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__pavlik_myenv_items_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pavlik_myenv_local:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__pavlik_myenv_items_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__pavlik_myenv_items_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl } % preserve spaces
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__pavlik_myenv_items_tl
   {
    \pavlik_myenv_temp:n { ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{#1 - }
\myLocalMacro{FOO BAR1}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR2}\par
\myLocalMacro{FOOBAR3}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\begin{myEnvironment}{#1, }
\myLocalMacro{TeX}\par
\myLocalMacro{abc}\par
\end{myEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

Here `\tl_map_inline:Nn` is the analog of `\@tfor`; before applying it, we change all spaces in the argument with `\c_space_tl`, whose expansion is a space.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can it handle empty spaces?
I need the output of `\myLocalMacro{ A }` to be ' - A - -'
In my definition this would have been handled by separating the arguments into {}. And `\myLocalMacro{}{A}{}` would do the trick.