# How to iterate through macro parameters in a for loop? or how to expand a macro parameter with a counter?

Tags: macros, counters, loops

I'm trying to expand a macro argument with a counter inside a for loop with the next code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{forloop}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m O{II} O{III} O{IV}}{
  \newcounter{i}
  \forloop{i}{1}{\thei < 5}{
    #1\thei : #\thei \quad
  }
}

\begin{document}

\test{A}

\end{document}
```

This yield two errors:

1. ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \test code.
2. ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.

I'm trying to achieve an output like this:

```
A1:A  A2:II  A3:III  A4:IV
```

i.e., I want to iterate through the macro parameters.

It seems that the problem is in the `#\thei` part. So some of the things I've tried so far are `\expandafter #\thei` or `\expandafter #\numexpr\thei\relax` without success.

I've been searching for information in *TeX by Topic* but I can't find anything helpful in this regard. I would appreciate some help if posssible!

---

Here I leave a fully compiling variant for testing purposes, this of course is not the desired behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{forloop}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m O{II} O{III} O{IV}}{
  \newcounter{i}
  \forloop{i}{1}{\thei < 5}{
    #1\thei : #1 \quad
  }
}

\begin{document}

\test{A}

\end{document}
```

which outputs:

```
A1:A  A2:A  A3:A  A4:A
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, maybe there is another way?

Comment: IIRC TeX does not expand tokens when looking for a number following `#`, so this cannot really work. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200283/82917. There might be other ways, but a detailed example of what the input and expected output should be would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The symbols `#1`, `#2` in macro body are interpreted as "points where actual parameter have to be inserted" and these symbols are saved to the macro body without any interpretation of surrounding tokens when `\def` is processed. It means that you cannot use `#\foo` where `\foo` is a macro which expands to `1`.

Your task can be solved by following macros:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\test #1{\tmpnum=0 \def\param{#1}\testA{}{II}{III}{IV}\end}
\def\testA #1{\ifx\end#1\relax\else
   \advance\tmpnum by1
   \param\the\tmpnum:\ifx^#1^\param \else#1\fi \space
   \expandafter\testA \fi
}

\test{A}

\bye
```

Comment: You failed to notice that `II`, `III` and `IV` are optional argument defaults. How would you cope with them?

Answer (score 4):

When TeX absorbs the replacement text for a macro it doesn't interpret tokens in any way. Using `\edef` is out of question either, because assignments are not performed in an `\edef` replacement text.

You can use an indirect method, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% we need a variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:Nn { NV }

% the template: first argument, index, colon, argument corresponding to index
\cs_new:Nn \__alvaro_aux:n { ##1#1:###1~ }

% set a tl to iterate the desired template
\exp_args:NNe \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \int_step_function:nN { 4 } \__alvaro_aux:n }

% define an internal function; \use:n is needed to reduce the number of #
\use:n { \cs_new:NV \alvaro_test:nnnn \l_tmpa_tl }

% the external function
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mO{II}O{III}O{IV}}
 {
  \alvaro_test:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{A}

\test{B}[1]

\test{C}[1][2]

\test{D}[1][2][3]

\end{document}
```

Well, it was interesting, because you can see `###1` (three `#` characters are not that common).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can try for expl3

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\test{m O{II} O{III} O{IV}}{
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist{#1,#2,#3,#4}
\int_step_inline:nn{4}
{
    #1##1: \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist{##1}\quad
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\test{A}\par
\test{A}[B][C][D]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't specify *why* you wish iteration I suggest to do without iteration:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m O{II} O{III} O{IV}}{%
  #11:#1\quad#12:#2\quad#13:#3\quad#14:#4%
}

\begin{document}

\test{A}

\test{B}[1]

\test{C}[1][2]

\test{D}[1][2][3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively you can have a loop for processing a list of default-values, in each iteration grabbing an optional argument and in case its value equals the `-NoValue-`-marker delivering the default-value coming from the list and otherwise delivering that optional argument:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\test{m}{%
  #11:#1\testloop{2}{#1}{II}{III}{IV}%<- here you can append more default-values if you wish TeX to process more optional arguments.
  {}{}\relax
}%
\@ifdefinable\testloop{%
  \long\def\testloop#1#2#3#4\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#4}$\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {\testloopopt{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\testloopopt{mmmmo}{%
  \quad#2#1:\IfNoValueTF{#5}{#3}{#5}%
  \expandafter\testloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}#4\relax
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{A}

\test{B}[1]

\test{C}[1][2]

\test{D}[1][2][3]

\end{document}
```

[image]