# Automatically include a sequence of images

Tags: beamer, graphics, automation, python

I want to include a sequence of images in Beamer (although it can be in another type of document). Something similar to the option *Photo Album* in LibreOffice and MS PowerPoint.

What I did is to make a template (that I can modify):

```
%s
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{%s}
    \framesubtitle{%s}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{%s} 
\end{frame}
```

And then I use a Python script to generate the code for each frame, like this:

```
tex_file = open(filename + '.tex', 'a+')
for name in list_files:
    print >> tex_file, s1 %(comment, title, subtitle, name)

tex_file.close()
```

After that I just use an `\include` in my main file to add the sequence of images.

**My question:** Is there a package for this task? or a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes you can do this with loops in (La)TeX... no problem. What does the sequence look like... `photo_001.jpg`, `photo_002.jpg`, ...?

Comment: Yes, I generate the  images automatically and name them like that: `im-vf=1.png`, `im-vf=2.png`, ...

Comment: Contrary to other answers, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457447/105409) for a similar question contains a method which does not require to rename the files with a specific pattern. It uses the `pgffor` package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an option using [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{9}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title: \i}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle: \i}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-\i}
  \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is `\multido{<var>=<start>+<inc>}{<times}{<stuff>}` which defines `<var>` to be `<start>`, incremented by `<inc>` a total of `<times>-1` times (since the first value counts as an iteration), and with each iteration it executes `<stuff>`. The special `\i`-notation means that `<var>` will be an `i`nteger.

The above example assumes minimal changes from one element to the next. If, for example, you have varied content for the frame title, subtitle and any additional comments on a per-photo basis, then using a list-like approach would be far better. For than, any of the techniques mentioned in [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful! Although the `\r` and `\n` variables are not perfect they work. For more elaborated things I will look at iteration over a CSV file.

Answer (score 9):

I have a tex file that I wrote to produce a display of photos that does something like this. For me the goal is to arrange a changing collection of photos on a grid covering the page. I use `tikz` to both loop over the photos, that are stored as a comma separated list of image filenames, and to place the photos.

As you are talking about generating the list of filenames via python you could easily populate a variable list like the one used below.

Here is a cut down version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\MyImages{example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}% list of images
\begin{document}
  \newdimen\X
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,
          picture/.style={draw,rectangle,anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
     ]
     \X=0mm
     \foreach \Image in \MyImages {
       \node[picture=north west] at (\X,-101.5mm)
             {\includegraphics[width=49.5mm,height=35mm]{\Image}};
       \global\advance\X by 49.5mm
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is possible using the `\multiinclude` command from beamer's `xmpmulti` package.

Assuming the images are called `fig-0.png`, `fig-1.png` etc. the macro can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{xmpmulti} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{fig}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```