# Insert multiple "unique" photos in one page in latex

Tags: floats

My attempt is to put multiple photos in a page, which are not related to each other. However, they overlap and making page look ugly. Is there a way to separate these photos?
the document class can be downloaded from [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates)

MWE :

```
    \documentclass{sig-alternate}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \begin{document}


    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=.35]{plot1.eps}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}


    %some text goes here and then...

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=.45]{plot2.eps}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Astrinus how about now?

Comment: Your example still doesn't 'work'. We need your image files to compile it. Without them it will be much more difficult to troubleshoot. Also, does the problem remain if you switch to a standard document class, like `article`? If so, you don't need to include your special document class in the example! On the other hand, if the problem only shows up with `\documentclass{sig-alternate}`, that's a big hint about where to start looking for the cause.

Comment: @Tyler you mean doesnt work like my code is not working or doesnt work like that it is ok with in your case?

Comment: @Tyler using article it just put each photo in different page, while i wish that both photos being placed in same page. and with that special document class. in fact i placed a link to download the class

Comment: If the images are overlapping then latex is not leaving space for them which indicates an error in the eps images (incorrect BoundingBox) as such it's hard to say what to fix as we don't have the images.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how to attach them?

Comment: You can't:-) but for a start you could try to generate an example using stock images `\includegraphics{example-image}` should work on a reasonably up to date tex distribution. If you can only make the problem with your images, the problem is your images, not tex, if you can make a generic example, post it...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what is a stock image? a new tex syntax?

Comment: No I mean if you use `\includegraphics{example-image}` latex will include an image that is included for this purpose in all modern tex distributions, which means that anyone trying your example will see the same output as you. But if you can not generate the  problem using that image, that is useful information, pointing to my initial guess that there is a problem with your eps files.

Comment: if you can find a minimal number of photos that produce this problem (say just two or three that overlap), could you upload those image files to flickr or some other image sharing site (maybe google drive would work)? Then we could check if @DavidCarlisle is correct and there is something wrong with the eps files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically include a sequence of images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202649/automatically-include-a-sequence-of-images)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `scale` but relative lengths in your `figure*` (**with the start if the float must fill both columns**, but note  that these floats are never placed in the page were is the code) or `figure` environment (for images in two columns).

N.B.: Today is usually better use PNG, JPG or PDF images with  `pdflatex` (or `xelatex`,  or `lualatex`) than EPS files with `latex` to avoid the `.dvi` > `.ps` > `.pdf`  conversion, or using `pdflatex` plus `epstopdf`, to avoid have both EPS and PDF versions of the same images in your working directory.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text for the example
    \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]    

    \begin{figure*}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure*}


    \begin{figure*}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-30]    

\end{document}
```

Comment: you say better in the sense of resolution quality?

Comment: @user1064929 No. Better in the sense that you working directory is not filled by `epstopdf` with PDF copies of the original EPS files. Better in the sense that  without `epstopdf`, your alternative is EPS + `latex`  only to start the  .tex > .dvi > .ps > .pdf conversion , while using  `pdflatex` without EPS files you obtain directly the PDF. Better in the sense of less working problems, because actually JPG, PNG and PDF are common formats,  but many people and programs  do not know what to do with a  EPS file.