# How to make TikZ matrix start a new row automatically when certain column number is reached?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I wish to set the maximum column count in a TikZ matrix and, if I start a new cell when the maximum count is reached, LaTeX would put the cell in a new row.

One approach would be a command which checks current column number and determine whether to be replaced by an `&` or a `\\`.

### Background:

I'm making PDF for printing on an array of self adhesive labels like this:
[image: self adhesive labels]

When creating my labels, I have to insert `\\` instead of `&` if current row is full, which is not convenient.
Sometimes I want to modify my file, i.e. remove an item, and I have to move every subsequent `\\` to make line breaks correct.

### Update:

The code is posted here to provide more explanation. I want to make every position of an element under my control so I anchored the matrix relative to the edge of paper. If there is no offset induced by printer, the bounding box generated by following code will coincide with pre-cut seam on paper.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{qrcode}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{xifthen} % provides \isempty test
    \usepackage{pst-barcode}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \newcommand{\Label}[2][]{
        \draw (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3cm,-4cm) node (framesoutheast) {};
        \path (0cm,0cm) -- node[midway,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,yshift=-4mm] (qrcode) {
            \begin{pspicture}(0.9in,0.9in)
                \psbarcode{https://wiki.thu-skyworks.org/#2}{width=0.9 height=0.9}{qrcode}
            \end{pspicture}
            %\qrcode[2cm]{https://wiki.thu-skyworks.org/#2}
            %\XeTeXinputencoding "utf8"
        }(3cm,0cm);
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt] (logo) at (0mm,-40mm) {\includegraphics[width=9mm]{any_square_image}};
        \path (logo.east) -- node[anchor=center,text width=19mm,align=center,font=\sffamily\small]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#1}}
        (logo.east-|framesoutheast);
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \matrix[row sep={4cm,between origins}, column sep = {32mm,between origins},matrix anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,xshift=10mm,yshift=-8mm] at (current page.north west) {
        %\XeTeXinputencoding "byte"
            \Label{Label\ one} & \Label[If need\\manual break]{If\ need\ manual\ break} & \Label{Label\ 3} &
            \Label{Label 4} & \Label{Label 5} & \Label{Label 6} \\ % I want to make this line break auto
            \Label{Label 7} \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you put them in a matrix? If you make the pictures the proper size and typeset them normally, the line breaking will do what you want.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202649/automatically-include-a-sequence-of-images/202657#202657

Comment: @PietvanOostrum because I need to specify distance between rows and columns, and specify their position on the page to mach the seam on the paper.

Comment: @Andrew using loops seems to be a good idea, will come back after some experiment, thanks!

Comment: @RuoxiWang But can that not be done by making the size of the figure just right?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I'm afraid it's not reliable. First, it seems that some unknown amount of white space will be added between figures and I don't want to get the spacing correct by trial and error. Second, as the content of labels is generated by LaTeX code via my custom macro, there's a chance that some mistake will make the size of the figure inconsistent. Third, seems that the size of figure will increase by a line thickness if I change the bounding box (a rect path) from not drawn to drawn for debugging purpose.

Comment: OK, I added a solution with a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter to count the labels. After each label increment the counter. If the counter is 6 you insert `\\` and reset the counter, otherwise insert `&` (or rather what the definition of `&` is in a matrix, namely `\pgfmatrixnextcell`).

```
\newcounter{colnr}
\setcounter{colnr}{0}
\newcommand{\lb}{%
  \stepcounter{colnr}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{colnr}=6}{\setcounter{colnr}{0}\\}{\pgfmatrixnextcell}%
}
```

Replace all `&` and `\\` in the matrix with `\lb`, except the final `\\`.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to a `TiKZ` matrix you can use a `tcbraster` construction from `tcolorbox`. You define `raster columns` value, and list all elements. `tcbraster` will distribute them and will break lines and pages when needed.

Following code shows how to declare it. Option `raster force size=false` keeps inner boxes size, otherwise inner `raster columns` boxes are scaled to fit into one text line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hmargin={1cm,1cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=6, raster every box/.style={blankest, width=3cm}, raster force size=false]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,20}{%
        \tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
        \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-A}
        \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-B}
        \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-C}
    }
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea! Will come back after some experiment, thanks!