# Placing 8 images in one page

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I would like to place 8 images in a single page, as following:

2 blocks of 4 images, where the name of each image is placed under it, and one general title for all of the four.

I tried the following code to make 4 images. However, it worked for me only with 2 next to each other.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[1]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{fig1}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[2]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{fig2}}}
    \\
    \subfloat[3]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{fig3}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[4]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{fig4}}}    
    \caption{graphs}%
\end{figure}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202649/automatically-include-a-sequence-of-images/202657#202657

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: The width of all the figures and spaces between them adds up to more than 20 cm, which is definitely wider than the textwidth of an a4 paper. You should therefor reduce the specified widths. Secondly, there is a `\\` which indicates a linebreak after the second and third image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `subfig` package, I would personally suggest the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[1]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[2]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[3]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[4]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}

    \subfloat[1]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[2]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[3]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[4]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}    
    \caption{graphs}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have specified the width of every image to be 22% of the textwidth. That way the images still fit even if the margins are changed. `\hfill` between neighbouring images ensures, that the images are horizontally evenly spread over the whole textwidth.

### update

As requested in the comments, this update includes a MWE showing the images in 2 columns with 4 rows each (instead of 4 columns with 2 rows).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[1]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[2]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}

    \subfloat[3]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[4]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}

    \subfloat[1]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[2]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}

    \subfloat[3]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[4]{{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}    
    \caption{graphs}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried those, however all solutions limit me in width of the paper. im trying to fit 8 images where there are 4 rows and 2 columns. is there any height to make it work? because I see pretty much empty space there.

Comment: @ben: I have misunderstood your initial question and have now edited my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mentioned code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:1} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:2} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:3} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:4} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{5} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{6} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{7} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{8} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{9} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{10} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{11} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{12} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{13} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}


\caption{Normal Models. \protect\subref{subfig:1} SLR. \protect\subref{subfig:2} MLR. \protect\subref{subfig:3} SWR. \protect\subref{subfig:4} OLS. \protect\subref{5} OLS. \protect\subref{6} OS. \protect\subref{7} Ok. \protect\subref{8} hi. \protect\subref{9} hey. \protect\subref{10} MSD. \protect\subref{11} LPY. \protect\subref{12} MSY. \protect\subref{13} Hello.}
\label{f45}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```