# Placing multiple images in a hierarchy using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an overview image (let's call it A) of the task. The task is divided into two. I have the detailed description of each sub-tasks (let's call it B and C).

I am trying to put them together using TikZ. I am trying to generate something similar to this-
[image]

See below the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{
  box/.style  = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, line width=0.5mm},
  line/.style = {line width=0.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image-a}};
  \node (b) [box, draw=green, fill=green!20, below of=a, yshift=-2cm] {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{image-b}};
  \node (c) [box, draw=orange, fill=orange!20, below of=b, yshift=-2cm] {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{image-c}};

  \coordinate[left of=a, xshift=-2cm] (t1);
  \coordinate[right of=a, xshift=2cm] (t2);

  \draw [line, draw=green] (a) -- (t1);
  \draw [line, draw=green] (t1) -- (b);

  \draw [line, draw=orange] (a) -- (t2);
  \draw [line, draw=orange] (t2) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code produces the following output-
[image]

Following are the issues with generated diagram-

- The positioning of the lines. The inclined lines aren't preferred. Better to use vertical lines.
- The orange line is going through image B, which doesn't look nice. It would be wise to keep it back.
- Lots of manual positioning is done in the code in order to place these images.

**How do I get the diagram similar to the first diagram? I would definitely prefer less manual positioning.**

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202649/automatically-include-a-sequence-of-images/202657#202657

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you very much. I checked the reference you have provided. Unfortunately it is different from my question. In my question (a) I want to place photos (b) connect them with lines in certain fashion. Hope it help.

Comment: Note that your code doesn't actually work, those images are called `example-image-a`, not `image-a. You should also have a look at [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : I already have `image-a.pdf` which is exactly same as `example-image-a`. I am sorry that this information wasn't provided. However the code works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the positioning, you're loading the `positioning` library, but you're not using its features. Use e.g. `below=of` not `below of=`. The latter is deprecated, and with that the distance is measured between node centers. With `below=of` the distance is measured between node borders. See [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

For the lines, you can make use of perpendicular coordinates and path specifications, see [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429) for explanation of that.

To place the red path behind the line, you can use the `backgrounds` library, and place the path `on background layer`.

If you want to avoid defining the `t1` and `t2` coordinates, you can replace the code for drawing the lines found below with this:

```
\draw [line, draw=green] (a) -| ([xshift=-1cm]a.west |- b.north);

\scoped[on background layer]
  \draw [line, draw=orange] (a) -| ([xshift=1cm]a.east |- c.north);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  backgrounds, % <-- added
  positioning
}

\tikzset{
  box/.style  = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, line width=0.5mm},
  line/.style = {line width=0.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm] % changed 2cm to 1cm
  \node (a) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};

  \node (b) [box, draw=green,
             fill=green!20, below=of a % use below=of
             ] {\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}};
  \node (c) [box, draw=orange, 
             fill=orange!20, below=of b] % below=of here as well
             {\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3cm]{example-image-c}};

  % left=of/right=of, not left of=/right of=
  \coordinate[left=of a] (t1);
  \coordinate[right=of a] (t2);


  \draw [line, draw=green] (a) -| (t1 |- b.north);

\scoped[on background layer] % means that the following path is placed on the background layer
  \draw [line, draw=orange] (a) -| (t2 |- c.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One quick question. Do I really need point t1 and t2? Since you are using -| notation, so I think it would automatically find the intermediate point.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Sounds like you haven't quite understood `-|`, it is `t1`/`t2` that defines the horizontal position of the corners of those paths, you need them for that. But you can remove them if you do something like `\draw [line, draw=green] (a) -| ([xshift=-1cm]a.west |- b.north);`.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1 sincerely.