# Include series of .png images into Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a folder containing files `fig-0.png`, `fig-1.png`, ... and so on. Since there are many files, to make things convenient is is possible to write some kind of a "for" loop such that beamer makes one image per-slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. This will work with your pictures as well, but the other users on this site won't have your pics so I use an example that loads pics that are part of the standard installations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {a,...,c,duck}
{\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{image \X}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-\X}
\end{frame}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just want to add that if the filenames in the list among brackets contain special characters (for instance `my_file.png`), they should be escaped (`my\_file.png`) to avoid a mess in the frame title. Fortunately, `includegraphics` will recognize them without problems.