# How to dynamically add items to the itemize

Tags: pdftex, itemize

At multiple instances in a document, i have to add a common section called Core courses. The core courses depending on the institution will vary.

For instance

Under one institution, i want to add the below courses

```
Core courses
1. Artificial Intelligence
2. Software Engineering
3. Software Architecture
4. Software Testing
5. Software Construction
```

At other particular place in the document, i will be adding the below.

```
    Core courses
1. Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition
2. Deep Learning
3. Reinforcement Learning
4. Text mining
```

Is it possible to write a new command (i.e \newcommand) in latex, which takes the subjects alone and formats them into an list.

Comment: The issue is simplify writing an itemize or enumerate environment ? In that case, run `texdoc wikicheat` ot `texdoc markdown`  before of  break your horns with a macro. Nonetheless I  am pretty sure that this kind of macro already exists somewhere in this site, but never it will so readable as using a simplified markup.

Comment: The first example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159132/134144) should suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\CoreCourses[2][Core courses]{
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\item ##1}
  \noindent\textsf{#1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \docsvlist{#2}
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\CoreCourses{
  Artificial Intelligence,
  Software Engineering,
  Software Architecture,
  Software Testing,
  Software Construction
}

\CoreCourses{
  Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition,
  Deep Learning,
  Reinforcement Learning,
  Text mining
}

\end{document}
```

The key is to use the `\docsvlist` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to convert a comma separated list into an enumerate environment.

As defined above, the `\CoreCourse` macro has an optional argument for setting the "title". The default is "Core Courses".

If you want to "style" the enumerate environment, I recommend using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

Here is the output:

[image]