# Is there a `for each` loop in primitive (La)TeX?

Tags: tex-core, loops, literate-programming

I am trying to iterate over the list of all basic colours:

```
\def\thecolors{black, blue, brown, cyan, darkgray, gray, green, lightgray, lime, magenta, olive, orange, pink, purple, red, teal, violet, white, yellow}
```

I want to define a command for each of them with some kind of `for each` loop, more or less as follows:

```
\foreach \x in \thecolors%
  {\newcommand{\csname command\x\endcsname}
    {\textcolor{\x}{Some text including the string \x.}}
```

I know this is more or less the way to do it with `pgf/tikz`, but I was wondering whether there is a way to do it only with (La)TeX primitive commands.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

**PS:** Do I need to explicitly define `\thecolors` or are LaTeX basic colours already stored in some command?

**EDIT**

I don't think this is a duplicate of [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118) since it explicitly asks for a (La)TeX primitive method.

Comment: You could try to use something like the `\loop` command but as far as I am aware there is no TeX primitive for dealing with comma separated lists, so you would have to implement this first. Easier alternatives would be to use [pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), as you suggest, or `\docsvlist` from [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, or `\clist_use:Nn` from [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/LaTeX3), or ...

Comment: Btw, there is no list (or even definition) of the "basic" colours but, for example, if you look at the manual for the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) you'll find related lists and ways of listing colour tables.

Comment: There is no primitive in TeX for this, but in the LaTeX2e kernel there is the `\@for` macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more “primitive” way in LaTeX, that also avoids the issues with grouping one gets with `\foreach`, would be

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\basiccolors{%
  black,blue,brown,cyan,darkgray,gray,green,lightgray,lime,%
  magenta,olive,orange,pink,purple,red,teal,violet,white,yellow%
}
\def\do@def#1{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname command#1\endcsname{%
    \textcolor{#1}{Some text including the string #1}%
  }%
}
\@for\next:=\basiccolors\do{\expandafter\do@def\expandafter{\next}}
\makeatother
```

Note that no spaces are allowed in the list of items.

It's *much* easier with `expl3`:

```latex
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makecommandsfromlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new:cpn { command ##1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makecommandsfromlist{
  black, blue, brown, cyan, darkgray, gray, green,
  lightgray, lime, magenta, olive, orange, pink,
  purple, red, teal, violet, white, yellow
}
{\textcolor{#1}{Some text including #1}}
```

Comment: Thank, @egreg. This was really something!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\@for` or an `expl3` list but often a more convenient (and a lot more efficient in terms of expansions) technique is to use a different structure which allows you to execute the list with no separate loop macro, this is explained in appendix D of the texbook and used in several places in latex (look for `\@elt` usage) I'll use `\\` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\thecolors{\\{black}\\{blue}\\{brown}\\{cyan}\\{darkgray}\\{gray}\\{green}\\{lightgray}\\{lime}\\{magenta}\\{olive}\\{orange}\\{pink}\\{purple}\\{red}\\{teal}\\{violet}\\{white}\\{yellow}}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


{%
\def\\#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname command#1\endcsname{%
    \textcolor{#1}{Some text including the string #1.}}}%
    \thecolors
}


\commandblue

\end{document}
```