# Iterate over comma separated values and optional argument

Tags: xparse, csv, literate-programming

I would like to adapt this [answer of another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159132/6880) for one optional argument but my MWE is just a M(not)WE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}


\newcommand\test[2]{#1+#2\par}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand\testcomas{O{x}m}{
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \test{#1}{##2} }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\testcomas{a, b ,c d, ,e }

\testcomas[T]{a, b ,c d, ,e }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\test{#1}{##1}` instead of `\test{#1}{##2}`. TeX's parameters are always numbered consecutively. The double hash means that your argument is nested by one additional level. (The documentation says that in `\clist_map_inline:Nn <comma list> {<inline function>}` `<inline function>` should be code that receives the item as `#1`, since you are in a function definition with parameters already, you need two `#`s to refer to this item.)

Comment: Shame on me ! Each time I see xparse, my three neurons run away. Thanks for helping them. :-)

Comment: I have started from this post but I have just done a very stupid thing. So the answer is in the post indicateed except for the optional argument but this is not hard to work with.