# LaTeX3: Parse CSV list stored in macro

Tags: latex3, loops, comma-separated-list

This question is kind-of follow-up to answer given to this question: [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list)

The difference is, that I want to iterate over a csv list stored in a macro `\myTerms`. In following MWE the list in `\myTerms` seems to be taken literally and not parsed as a CSV. I tryed to fix it with `\expanded{}`, but it doesnt seem to work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myList}{mm}
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 } { #2 } { #2 }
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mySeparator}{\textbullet}

\newcommand{\makeMyList}[1]{
  \begingroup
    \scshape\myList{#1}{\mySeparator}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\myTerms}{test, another test}

\begin{document}
\makeMyList{\expanded{\myTerms}}
\end{document}
```

Desired output is achieved when I am not using macro `myTerms` and simply write out the list to `\makeMyList` argument, like so:

Desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myList}{mm}
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 } { #2 } { #2 }
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mySeparator}{\textbullet}

\newcommand{\makeMyList}[1]{
  \begingroup
    \scshape\myList{#1}{\mySeparator}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\makeMyList{test, another test}
\end{document}
```

That led me to think that expansion control with `\expanded{}` is needed, but I seem to be making a different mistake. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `expl3` I'd advocate to stick to the means of expansion provided by that as long as you don't do low-level programming. What I mean with that is: you shouldn't have to bother to expand the list as input, I think it's better to let that be handled at the `expl3` level.

Your usage of `\expanded` doesn't work, because before `\expanded` can do its job your `\makeMyList` will grab its arguments and treat `\expanded{\myTerms}` as the input, doesn't find a comma and so uses that as a single term.

The expansion at the `expl3` level could be done in two different ways:

- educated guess, if only a single argument is provided it is very likely that this is a macro storing the values
- provide a "switch" at `\makeMyList`, e.g., via a star, in which case we could use `\exp_args:No` or similar.

The following implements *both*, but uses `\expandafter` for the second approach instead of the `expl3`-layer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myList}{mm}
  {
    \tl_if_single:nTF {#1}
      {
        % if the single item is a group we don't expand it
        \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF
          { \clist_set:Nn }
          {
            % if it's no group it must be N-type, and the test for group is
            % faster
            % there might be spaces around #1 but those will be removed by TeX's
            % argument grabbing, so don't hurt
            \token_if_expandable:NTF #1
              \clist_set:NV
              \clist_set:Nn
          }
      }
      { \clist_set:Nn }
        \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mySeparator}{\textbullet}

\NewDocumentCommand \makeMyList { s m }
  {
    \begingroup
      \scshape
      \IfBooleanTF {#1}
        {\expandafter\myList\expandafter{#2}\mySeparator}
        {\myList{#2}\mySeparator}%
    \endgroup
  }

\newcommand{\myTerms}{test, another test}

\begin{document}
% expansion-guess at the expl3 level
\makeMyList{\myTerms}\par
\makeMyList{\myTerms,abc}

% expansion of first token in the list by the interface
\makeMyList*{\myTerms}\par
\makeMyList*{\myTerms,abc}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** added more tests as suggested by [@AndrewStacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614992/latex3-parse-csv-list-stored-in-macro/615001?noredirect=1#comment1536178_615001).

[image]

Comment: You could further test to see if that one character in the single token list was active.

Comment: @AndrewStacey better tests added.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your proposal is that the `\expanded` doesn't get seen until too late. Depending on exactly what it is you want to achieve, there are a few ways to do this. A simple one is to change the `\clist_set:Nn` to `\clist_set:NV`. This takes the *value* of the macro as the list to use. You'd also need to remove the braces around the `#1`.  This does a single expansion so if your list contains macros then they don't get expanded.

(I'm not on a device where I can easily test this right now so it is possible that you'd need some other tweaks.)