Error Handling for TeX Command Definition with Spaces in Arguments
I'm currently working with TeX to define a command, as shown below:
\def\@fancybook@reset@counter#1,#2\stop{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \else
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%
  \else%
    \@fancybook@reset@counter#2\stop%
  \fi%
}

\def\fancybook@reset@counter#1{%
  \@fancybook@reset@counter#1,\stop%
}

When I use:
\fancybook@reset@counter{section,subsection}

everything works fine. However, when I try:
\fancybook@reset@counter{section, subsection}

TeX throws an error, saying "No counter ' subsection'". How can I modify the code to handle spaces in the arguments and avoid this error?
Ps: I don't want to use LaTeX3.
MWE:
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter
\def\@fancybook@reset@counter#1,#2\stop{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \else
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%
  \else%
    \@fancybook@reset@counter#2\stop%
  \fi%
}

\def\fancybook@reset@counter#1{%
  \@fancybook@reset@counter#1,\stop%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\fancybook@reset@counter{section,subsection} % working
% \fancybook@reset@counter{section, subsection} % not work
\makeatother
\end{document}


Which format are you using? Are you able to provide an example which reproduces the error? You can test to see if the next token is a space and discard it if it is. I don't know whether that's the best way to do it. I imagine there's something more succinct.

When you say no LaTeX3, can you say why? I'm wondering how much of it you want to avoid: just expl3 syntax or e.g. \ExpandArgs?

thanks, because I am interested in plain TeX. I only want to use plain TeX.

Then why are you using LaTeX? You aren't even loading plain if you're using LaTeX. Counters are a LaTeX thing. \setcounter is LaTeX. plain is a distinct format. Just as latex and context are formats. (Well, context is more complicated, if I remember correctly.)

expl3 can be loaded in plain ...

your example does not use any plain tex at all. if you want to handle a comma list without using L3 you could use the keyval package which is part of the core latex tools distribution.

Sorry, I wasn't clear earlier. I'm not limited to just plain TeX. I simply want to implement a comma-separated list without relying on any predefined commands like pgffor, l3clist, and so on.

With \newcounter, \setcounter, \stepconter, \refstepcounter and things like \arabic you can have counter names with spaces and/or commas. (You might need to construct \the(H)<counter> via \csname..\endcsname.) How to handle such edge cases?

Removing leading spaces is not really so difficult. Trailing spaces are more difficult, but the problem has been solved in several ways and there's no point in reinventing hot water.
Also managing comma separated lists has been available in the LaTeX kernel from day one:

with \@for (from the LaTeX kernel) you can process more than two items;

with trimspaces you can remove spaces from either end.


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetcounters}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \trim@spaces@in{\next}%
    \setcounter{\next}{0}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{100}
\setcounter{subsection}{5}

chapter: \thechapter; section: \thesection; subsection: \thesubsection

\resetcounters{ chapter ,section, subsection}

chapter: \thechapter; section: \thesection; subsection: \thesubsection

\end{document}


Here I exploit that \setcounter implicitly expands its first argument. In other situations you might need to expand \next. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2952/4427 for an example.
Now, for completeness, the one liner expl3 version.
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\resetcounters}{m}{\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \setcounter{##1}{0} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{100}
\setcounter{subsection}{5}

chapter: \thechapter; section: \thesection; subsection: \thesubsection

\resetcounters{ chapter ,section, subsection}

chapter: \thechapter; section: \thesection; subsection: \thesubsection

\end{document}


I found the answer in pgf:
\catcode`\Q=3
\def\fancybook@trimspaces#1{%
\romannumeral-`0\fancybook@trimspaces@\noexpand#1Q Q}
\def\fancybook@trimspaces@#1 Q{\fancybook@trimspaces@@#1Q}
\def\fancybook@trimspaces@@#1Q#2{#1}
\catcode`\Q=11

\def\@fancybook@reset@counter#1,#2\stop{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \else
    \setcounter{\fancybook@trimspaces{#1}}{0}%
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%
  \else%
    \@fancybook@reset@counter#2\stop%
  \fi%
}

\def\fancybook@reset@counter#1{%
  \@fancybook@reset@counter#1,\stop%
}

