# \@ne \tw@ \thr@@

Tags: macros, tex-core

The LaTeX (2e) source code is quiet hard to read. There are a lot of macros with `@` symbol. I understand those are "latex macros".

There is, in particular, a series of macros called `\@ne`, `\tw@`, `\thr@@` (and maybe more). Their `\meaning` is `\char"1`, `\char"2`, `\char"3`. I wonder (1.) how and where those are defined?

Further interests:
They seem to be used mainly to identify internal registers. "The Texbook" mentions that there are 256 internal registers of each type, e.g. `\box0` ... `\box256`. So which register does `\box\@ne` denote?

After reading Martin's answer I reached to the texbook, page 121:

> Besides
>   `\newcount`, plain TEX provides
>   `\newdimen`, `\newskip`, `\newmuskip`, and
>   `\newbox`; there also are `\newtoks`,
>   `\newread`, `\newwrite`, `\newfam`, and
>   `\newinsert`, for features we haven’t
>   discussed yet. Appendices B and E
>   contain several examples of the
>   proper use of allocation. In the cases
>   of `\newbox`, `\newread`, etc., the
>   allocated number is deﬁned by
>   `\chardef`. For example, if the command
>   "`\newbox\abstract`" is used to deﬁne a
>   box register that will contain an
>   abstract, and if the `\newbox` operation
>   decides to allocate `\box45` for this
>   purpose, then it deﬁnes the meaning of
>   `\abstract` by saying
>   "`\chardef\abstract=45`". TEX allows
>   `\chardef`’d quantities to be used as
>   integers, so that you can say
>   `\box\abstract` and `\copy\abstract`, etc.
>   (There is no `\boxdef` command.)

... so `\box\@ne` is equal to `\box1` ?

Comment: It's `\@ne` not `\@one`. There is also `\m@ne` for -1.
Edit: You have it correct in the text but not in the headline.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.se, and good question!  I took the liberty of formatting your post a bit.  Take a look at the [Editing Help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page for tips.

Comment: BTW, the `@` macros are in plain TeX as well.  Just open your TeXBook to Appendix B.

Comment: See also this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/saving-a-100-tokens-worth-is-it-worth-it

Comment: o-o ... lots to read still ... thanks @Matthew for the hint to Appendix B

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They are defined in `latex.ltx` starting from line 293:

```
\chardef\@ne=1
\chardef\tw@=2
\chardef\thr@@=3
\chardef\sixt@@n=16
\chardef\@cclv=255
```

And then on line 316:

```
\countdef\m@ne=22 \m@ne=-1
```

They are defined to reduce the numbers of tokens in the source code.

### Edit:

To answer your 2nd, later added question "... so `\box\@ne` is equal to `\box1`?"

**Yes!**

### Supplement:

There are also the very useful `\p@` and `\z@`, also defined in `latex.ltx` lines 353 and 354 (with original comments):

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
\newdimen\z@ \z@=0pt % can be used both for 0pt and 0
```

Example:
I encountered recently the expression `\wd\z@\z@` which at first confused me quite a bit. It means: "set the width of box 0 (`\z@` taken as integer) to 0pt (`\z@` used as dimension as normal). The longer form would be `\wd0=0pt` (6 tokens instead of 3).

Also `\p@` is very often used to add the 'pt' after a floating point number: `1.2345\p@` is 1.2345pt (actually 1.2345 x 1pt).

## See also:

In the meantime I compiled a [list of these and more macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465).

Comment: which speeds up compilation time

Comment: and makes it possible to use them as macro arguments without braces. I forget to mention that as well.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot to martin and herbert! i don't yet see how replacing "1" by "\@ne" either reduces the number of tokens (1 and 1 ?) or enables macro arguments without braces though. "1" is one token, so how do "\box1bla", "\box\@ne bla" and "\box{1}" (which i think will not work anyway) differ ?

Comment: For the \@ne macro it doesn't make much difference in your example, except that it removes trailing spaces like all macros. But e.g. for \m@ne. Also you can say \let\mymacro\@ne which is something completely different than \let\mymacro1. Ok, \def\mymacro{1} is a good alternative here :-)

Comment: @Patrick: From Appendix B: "(Notice that the long form of `\@ne` is ‘1 ’ including a space, because TeX looks for and removes a space following a constant.)"

Comment: I looked into this a little more and figured that all macros defined using `\chardef` are not expandable (the act like primitives). If used in an context where TeX scans for a number (e.g. `\ifnum`, assignments) it successfully terminates the scanning process, so that no other macro behind it are expanded. Like Hendrik said it acts like `'1 '`, but still is different as `\def\@ne{1 }` because of the unexpandability.

Answer (score 11):

One thing that I like about ConTeXt is that such internal macros are named in a more readable manner. For example, the corresponding definitions in ConTeXt are:

```
\countdef   \zerocount              =   120 \zerocount              =  0
\countdef   \plusone                =   121 \plusone                =  1
\countdef   \minusone               =   122 \minusone               = -1
```

and

```
\chardef    \plustwo            =     2
\chardef    \plusthree          =     3
\chardef    \plusfour           =     4
\chardef    \plusfive           =     5
\chardef    \plussix            =     6
\chardef    \plusseven          =     7
\chardef    \pluseight          =     8
\chardef    \plusnine           =     9
\chardef    \plusten            =    10
\chardef    \plussixteen        =    16
\chardef    \plushundred        =   100
\chardef    \pluscxxvii         =   127
\chardef    \pluscxxviii        =   128
\chardef    \pluscclv           =   255
```

These are not "protected", so the user can redefine them. So, ConTeXt does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. There is a protected version of some of the these (defined as macros rather than counters; I don't know the implication on efficiency):

```
\def\!!zerocount {0} % alongside \zerocount
\def\!!minusone {-1} % alongside \minusone
\def\!!plusone   {1} % alongside \plusone
\def\!!plustwo   {2} % alongside \plustwo
\def\!!plusthree {3} % alongside \plusthree
```

These are much easier to read than the corresponding plain TeX definitions (that are more or less copied in LaTeX).

Comment: As macros, I think they're going to be slower since it has to expand the macro, see the number and then keep expanding macros looking for more numbers or the optional space. I guess you could use `\!!plusthree\!!plusone` to get `31`, but that seems sort of silly.