# What do \m@ne‎ and \@M do in the definition of \@makechapterhead?

Tags: macros, latex-base

What do `\m@ne`‎ and `\@M` do in the definition of `\@makechapterhead` in book class?
I took a quick look at `latex.ltx` and couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: `\m@ne` is the constant `-1`, while `\@M` stands for `10000`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\m@ne` stands for *minus one*, i.e. is a `count` register with a fixed value of -1, which is used for efficiency reasons over a literal `-1`.

`\@M` is defined using `\mathchardef` and equal to `\mathchar"2710`, i.e. 10000, and is used for the same reasons like above.

See the question [\@ne \tw@ \thr@@](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/ne-tw-thr/9788#9788) for more details on the reasons.
See also [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands) for a list of further similar macros. I also can recommend you `latexdef` (or `texdef -t latex`) to test for the definitions of such macros, e.g. `latexdef m@ne @M` will give you the definition and numerical values of these two macros.

Comment: Why doesn't one use the same -1 instead of `\m@ne`? Isn't `\m@ne` confusing?

Comment: It's used mainly for efficience (one token instead of two), but also because it avoids possible premature expansion of tokens after it.

Answer (score 5):

The file [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) is the correct one.

At line 316 you find `\m@ne`:

```
\countdef\m@ne=22 \m@ne=-1
```

At line 300 you find `\@M`:

```
\mathchardef\@M=10000
```