# What does \z@ do?

Tags: macros, latex-base

in parcolumns it has `\z@` all over the space. I don't see it define it anywhere so I assume it is some internal command or something? I can't really make heads or tails of it though and I can't really search google for it(doesn't return anything useful)

Comment: First Google hit for `latex z`: http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/doc-z.html

Comment: @Jake Unfortunately the title of the page Tralics: a LaTeX to XML translator (Z) is very deceiving. Good site reference though as it clued me in to a lot of macros I couldn't find in some others references.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/ne-tw-thr

Comment: See also [What does `\p@` mean in some code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38664/5764)

Comment: Ironically, googling `LaTeX \z@` led me right to this page

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`\z@` is a LaTeX “constant” that's defined to be zero.  Package developers can use it to assign or test against the value `0` and it can also replace a length of `0pt`.  Similar constants are `\@ne` (one) `\tw@` (two) and so on.  Due to the `@` they can only be used in packages or between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 104):

`latex.ltx` says

```
\newdimen\z@ \z@=0pt % can be used both for 0pt and 0
```

so as it says it is short (and efficient) way of getting 0.

You should always have a copy of the latex source file `latex.ltx` in a text editor window while reading package code:-), or perhaps, if you prefer, the typeset version of that, without the comments being removed, `source2e.pdf`, this is available in most distributions, or may be typeset from the sources.

Note that `\count@=\z@` is more efficient than `\count@=0` as `\z@` is a register so terminates the scan for a number. But `0` might be the first token in `0123` so TeX has to read ahead to find the next token, if it is a space, discard it, if it is anything else it needs to put the token back into its input stream to be read after the assignment.

---

A Test file:

```
\catcode`@=11
%\def\a{\dimen@=\z@}
\def\a{\dimen@=0pt\relax}
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}
\def\c{\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b}
\def\d{\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c}
\def\e{\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d}
\def\f{\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e}
\def\g{\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f}
\def\h{\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g}

\h

\bye
```

Doing a few runs of each two and taking a typical timing, with 0pt as above:

```
$ time tex zat
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011/Cygwin)
(./zat.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on zat.log.

real    0m3.822s
user    0m3.774s
sys     0m0.015s
```

With the % moved a line so it uses `\z@`:

```
$ time tex zat
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011/Cygwin)
(./zat.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on zat.log.

real    0m1.080s
user    0m1.029s
sys     0m0.030s
```

This is an easily observable difference, even without using the time command. 10^7 is quite a few assignments but probably not impossibly many.

Comment: I understand that parsing a macro is more efficient in principle.  Just wondering: Does that have a noticable effect in practice?

Comment: @ilpssun I think you have that backwards, `\z@` is more efficient because it is _not_ a macro, but a register. It was certainly noticeable in the 1980's when the definition was made (as in the difference between only having time for a coffee and having time to go for lunch) To actually notice (rather than measure) the difference now you probably have to have a very big document doing an awful lot of assignments.

Comment: Okay, now I get it.  Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It still shows up to some extent, certainly in the more general case of 'integer constants as registers rather than numerals'. See the fact that in `expl3` we still use a lot of count registers: there is an impact.

Comment: To the reader wondering "what's an `emacs` buffer?" I would suggest keeping `source2e.pdf` handy.  It's in most TeX distributions.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, hard as it is to imagine someone not using emacs, you make a good point I should keep my editor bias out of the question, I'll reword:-)

Comment: @JosephWright, this still doesn't explain why registers are used rather than constants. =]  Is it purely historical or are there modern-day performance implications?

Comment: @AlexHirzel I don't understand what you mean by 'constants': in TeX, apart from a few primitives, a constant is just a macro or register that we don't change by convention. In `expl3`, we still use registers for these integer 'constant-by-conventions' as there is a performance gain.

Comment: (Actually, it's a bit more complex as we _do_ use `\chardef` and `\mathchardef` to create smaller positive integer constants.)

Comment: I'll add some figures to my answer

Comment: So in a typical Latex class file, if I were to rewrite all measurements in the more readable form, e.g. "0pt" can I assume there would not be a noticeable difference on a fast modern computer?

Comment: @user42645 unless the length setting is in a macro to be used thousands of times it will be hard to measure the difference let alone notice it. But beware of the need for trailing space or \relax

Comment: It would be nice to add similar with usage within `\numexpr` (I compared `\count@=\numexpr\z@+\z@+\z@\relax` with `0+0+0`). There isn't as much a difference as in your test but still it shows.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look it up at the index of the *TeXbook*

> `\z@` is used quite often to stand for either `0pt`  or `0`

p. 348, Appendix B