# How to correct the table of contents title?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

Here is my codes:

```
    % This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.4
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Headings and outline numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0.0cm}{0.1665in}{0.0835in}{\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor\fontsize{18.2pt}{21.84pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname @textstyle#1\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}\csname @distance#1\endcsname}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand\@distancesection{}
\newcommand\@textstylesection[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom
% Paragraph styles
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
% List styles
\newcommand\writerlistleftskip{}
\newcommand\writerlistparindent{}
\newcommand\writerlistlabel{}
\newcommand\writerlistremovelabel{\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistparindent\aftergroup\relax\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistlabel\aftergroup\relax}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[bluelace,screen,nopanel,sectionbreak]{pdfscreen}
%\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={FullScreen}}
\margins{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\screensize{6in}{8in}
\sloppy
\title{Data Cleaning Method}
\author{Amin Karimi}
\date{2017-07-16}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Investigating methods of cleaning dataset in high frequency data literature}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Why the table of contents title is .0cmcontents?

Comment: ... [What does \z@ do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55402/124842)

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the low-level re-definition of `\section`. Redefining the sections format with `titlesec` solved the problem.

I took the liberty to replace `color`with `xcolor`, and `palatino` with `\newpxtext, newpxmath`, so that a palatino-clone is used for both text and math. Last point, I commented 4 `\newcommand{\writerlistxxx}{}`, which seem to be written by `writer2latex`: they do nothing, and I don't what they're here for.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, supertabular, hhline}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Headings and outline numbering
 \titleformat*{\section}{\color{section0}\normalfont\fontsize{18.2pt}{21.84pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\raggedbottom
% Paragraph styles
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
% List styles
%%% The following four commands seem to be defined by writer2latex. I don’t understand what they should do in a normal . tex file.
%%% Uncomment if necessary
%\newcommand\writerlistleftskip{}
%\newcommand\writerlistparindent{}
%\newcommand\writerlistlabel{}
%\newcommand\writerlistremovelabel{\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistparindent\aftergroup\relax\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistlabel\aftergroup\relax}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}%%% replaces palatino. Uses a -palatino clone (TeX Gyre Pagella) for text and maths. Has a euro symbol
\usepackage[bluelace,screen,nopanel,sectionbreak]{pdfscreen}%
%\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={FullScreen}}
\margins{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\screensize{6in}{8in}
\sloppy
\title{Data Cleaning Method}
\author{Amin Karimi}
\date{2017-07-16}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

\section{Investigating methods of cleaning dataset in high frequency data literature}

Here is the output:

\end{document}
```

[image]