# How can I avoid newline when adjustwidth and eqnarray?

Tags: equations, adjustwidth

`adjustwidth` inserts a redundant newline only when it is used with `eqnarray`. How can I avoid it?

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Hello World!
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
Hello World!
\end{adjustwidth}

\ \\
Hello World!
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}

\ \\
Hello World!
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Output with caption:

[image]

As far as I measure with a ruler, the height of the space is doubled when with `adjustwidth`.

---

MWE input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=30truemm,bottom=30truemm,left=25truemm,right=25truemm]{geometry}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\bmk}{{\bm{k}}}
\newcommand{\brac}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\expo}[1]{e^{#1}}
\newcommand{\ao}[1]{a_{#1}}
\newcommand{\aod}[1]{a^\dagger _{#1}}

\begin{document}

Operator $A$ is defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& \sum _{\bmk _1, \bmk _2} \Braket{\bmk _1, \uparrow | \hat{A} | \bmk _2, \uparrow} \left\{ \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2} - \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} + \eta \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow}} \right. \nonumber \\
&\ & \hspace{3cm} \left. + \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2} + \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} + \eta \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow}} \right\}.
\end{eqnarray}

The Heisenberg representation of this gives 
\begin{eqnarray}
A(t) &=& \sum _{\bmk _1, \bmk _2} \Braket{\bmk _1, \uparrow | \hat{A} | \bmk _2, \uparrow} \left\{ \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2} - \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t} + \eta \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t}} \right. \nonumber \\
&\ & \hspace{1.5cm} \left. + \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2} + \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} + \eta \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} } \right\}.
\end{eqnarray}

The Heisenberg representation of this gives 
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{eqnarray}
A(t) &=& \sum _{\bmk _1, \bmk _2} \Braket{\bmk _1, \uparrow | \hat{A} | \bmk _2, \uparrow} \left\{ \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2} - \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t} + \eta \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t}} \right. \nonumber \\
&\ & \hspace{1.5cm} \left. + \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2} + \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2}} \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} + \eta \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} } \right\}.
\end{eqnarray}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

MWE output:

[image]

Eq(2) is written without `adjustwidth`. That is enough when I see the pdf on my computer, but the right edge part will vanish when printed. Eq(3) is written with `adjustwidth`. Is is readable and printable. However, there is a redundant space inserted. (In Eq(2) or Eq(3), a single equation is broken into two lines. I don't wanna break the equation anymore (into three or more lines).)

Comment: (i) instead eqnarray` is better to use `align` or similar math environment from `asmath` package, (ii) for one line equation the use of multi line math environment hasn't any sense  (iii) for what purposes you insert equations into reduced text width (made by`adjustwidth`), and not at the end, (iv) please extend your code fragment to complete small document (MWE:  Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for you comment. (i) I know... (ii) I know. (iii)(iv) Please see my edit. I added MWE.

Comment: if you know, why than you use`eqnarray`? after editing your question it seems that use of `multline` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code `changepage.sty` shows

```
\newenvironment{adjustwidth}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \topsep\z@%
    \listparindent\parindent%
    \parsep\parskip%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{\setlength{\rightmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}}%
    }
    \item[]}{\end{list}}
```

(These links may help you understand the code above: [What does \z@ do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/what-does-z-do) and [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300418/109566))

So the problem is not due to `adjustwidth` but due to `eqnarray`. The `list` environment gives you one line for an item, but `eqnarray` automatically inserts a newline, so the space is widened. Margin settings are irrelevant, and the same problem can be reproduced with `itemize`. For example,

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

So the solution is to move the text into `adjustwidth` environment.

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=30truemm,bottom=30truemm,left=25truemm,right=25truemm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\ \\ % normal
Hello World!
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}

\ \\ % with adjustwidth
Hello World!
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}
\end{adjustwidth}

\ \\ % solution
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\hspace{1.0cm}Hello World! % note that this text is INSIDE the environment
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

This is what I wanted though this sticks to deprecated `eqnarray`...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `split`. Never use `eqnarray` with LaTeX, prefer the alignment environments offered by `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=30truemm,bottom=30truemm,left=25truemm,right=25truemm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\bmk}{\bm{k}}
\newcommand{\brac}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\expo}[1]{e^{#1}}
\newcommand{\ao}[1]{a_{#1}}
\newcommand{\aod}[1]{a^\dagger_{#1}}
\newcommand{\up}{{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\down}{{\downarrow}}

\begin{document}

Operator $A$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A = 
\sum_{\bmk_1, \bmk_2} \braket{\bmk_1, \up | \hat{A} | \bmk_2, \up} \bigl\{
& 
  (\cos\theta_{\bmk_1} \cos\theta_{\bmk_2} - \eta \sin\theta_{\bmk_1} \sin\theta_{\bmk_2})
  (\aod{\bmk_1, \up} \ao{\bmk_2, \up} + \eta \aod{- \bmk_2, \down} \ao{- \bmk_1, \down}) \\
{}+{} &
  (\cos\theta_{\bmk_1} \sin\theta_{\bmk_2} + \eta \sin\theta_{\bmk_1} \cos\theta_{\bmk_2})
  (\aod{\bmk_1, \up} \aod{- \bmk_2, \down} + \eta \ao{- \bmk_1, \down} \ao{\bmk_2, \up})
  \bigr\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The Heisenberg representation of this gives 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A(t) = \sum_{\bmk_1, \bmk_2} &\braket{\bmk_1, \up | \hat{A} | \bmk_2, \up}
\\
{}\cdot\bigl\{&
  (\cos\theta_{\bmk_1} \cos\theta_{\bmk_2} - \eta \sin\theta_{\bmk_1} \sin\theta_{\bmk_2})
  (\aod{\bmk_1, \up} \ao{\bmk_2, \up} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk_1} - 
    E_{\bmk_2}) t} + \eta \aod{- \bmk_2, \down} \ao{- \bmk_1, \down} 
    \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk_1} - E_{\bmk_2}) t})
\\
{}+{}&
  (\cos\theta_{\bmk_1} \sin\theta_{\bmk_2} + \eta \sin\theta_{\bmk_1} \cos\theta_{\bmk_2})
  (\aod{\bmk_1, \up} \aod{- \bmk_2, \down} \expo{\frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk_1} + E_{\bmk_2}) t} +
     \eta \ao{- \bmk_1, \down} \ao{\bmk_2, \up} 
     \expo{- \frac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk_1} + E_{\bmk_2}) t}) \bigl\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes: I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands, that give too big fences all around. Also I defined `\up` and `\down`, because `\uparrow` and `\downarrow` are relation symbols and may produce bad spacing if used as ordinary symbols. The braces in the definition make `\up` and `\down` behave like ordinary symbols everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `eqnarray` -- use `align` instead. Second, no need to resort to `adjustwidth` sledgehammer if you insert a few additional line breaks. For enhanced readability, consider using `\exp`-notation inside the `\expo` macro, as is done in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\bmk}{{\bm{k}}}
\newcommand{\brac}[1]{\Bigl( #1 \Bigr)}
\newcommand{\expo}[1]{\exp\bigl(#1\bigr)}
\newcommand{\ao}[1]{a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\aod}[1]{a^\dagger _{#1}}

\begin{document}

Operator $A$ is defined as
\begin{align}
A &= \sum _{\bmk _1, \bmk _2} 
\Braket{\bmk _1, \uparrow | \hat{A} | \bmk _2, \uparrow}
\Bigl\{ 
  \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2} 
  - \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2}} \notag\\
&\qquad\times\brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} 
  + \eta \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow}} \nonumber \\
&\quad+ \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2} 
  + \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2}} 
  \brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} 
  + \eta \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow}}
\Bigr\}.\\
\intertext{The Heisenberg representation of this gives}
A(t) &= \sum _{\bmk _1, \bmk _2}
\Braket{\bmk _1, \uparrow | \hat{A} | \bmk _2, \uparrow}
\Bigl\{
  \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2} 
  - \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2}} \notag\\
&\qquad\times\brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} 
  \expo{\tfrac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t} 
  + \eta \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} 
  \expo{- \tfrac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} - E_{\bmk _2}) t}} \nonumber \\
&\quad + \brac{\cos \theta _{\bmk _1} \sin \theta _{\bmk _2} 
  + \eta \sin \theta _{\bmk _1} \cos \theta _{\bmk _2}} \notag\\
&\qquad\times\brac{\aod{\bmk _1, \uparrow} \aod{- \bmk _2, \downarrow} 
  \expo{\tfrac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} 
  + \eta \ao{- \bmk _1, \downarrow} \ao{\bmk _2, \uparrow} 
  \expo{- \tfrac{i}{\hbar} (E_{\bmk _1} + E_{\bmk _2}) t} } 
\Bigr\}\,.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```