# Use relative units in the preamble

Tags: macros, sectioning, units, unit-of-measure

I use relative units to redefine the subsection as follows:

```
\documentclass[reqno,twoside]{svmult}


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}% reset chapter number when a new part starts

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
{\z@}{.7\linespacing\@plus.8\linespacing}{.3\linespacing}%
{\normalfont\bfseries\noindent}}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
{\z@}{-.5\linespacing\@plus.5\linespacing}{.2\linespacing}%
{\normalfont\noindent\bfseries\slshape}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
{\z@}{-.5\linespacing\@plus.3\linespacing}{.2\linespacing}%
{\normalfont\noindent\color{blue}}}

\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}%
{\z@}{-.3\linespacing\@plus.2\linespacing}{.1\linespacing}%
{\normalfont\slshape\noindent\color{blue}}}

\makeatother


\renewcommand*\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}% section 1.1
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}% subsection 1.1.1
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}} %subsubsection1.1.1.1



\begin{document}
\part{A}
\chapter{AA}
\section{AAA}
\subsection{AAAA}
\subsubsection{AAAAA}
\paragraph{BBBBBBBB}
\subparagraph{BBBBBBBB}
\end{document}
```

It works when I use the class AMSBook, However it show me the following wrong message when I use the SpringBook class 'svmult'.

```
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

Is there any way to make the class know this **relative unit**: "\linespacing"?

**P.S.** I use "\noindent" in the last as I don't want the indent. I still get an error when I delete it.

Comment: please provide a small test file that shows that error, by default there is no command `\linespacing` so the code shown would generate an undefined command error not the error shown

Comment: Unrelated but the `\noindent` in that definition is wrong and will break the standard latex section syntax

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi. I just make the revision and attach the full test code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In amsart `\linespacing` is defined by

```
\newdimen\linespacing
\normalsize \linespacing=\baselineskip
```

so it's just `\baselineskip` as set at the document default size.

You could use the same definition in other classes, or use other font dependent values suc as `ex` units or simply `\baselineskip`

It is unlikely that the error you show is the first error, with `article` class the first error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> .7\linespacing 
                          \@plus .8\linespacing 
l.11 \subsection
                {aaa}
?
```

and you only get the missing unit error if you scroll past this error. Later errors are often spurious TeX's recovery from errors often leaves it in a state where more errors are generated.

unrelated to the error but the `\noindent` should not be in the definition. To suppress indentation simply negate the 4th argument of `\@startsection` using `\noindent` in the section definition will generate spurious white paragraphs

Comment: Thanks. When I replace "\linespacing" by "\baselineskip". Everything works now. I also change the "\noindent" to the right position.

Comment: @Xliu glad you got it working but `\noindent` should not be used at all. LaTeX never uses `\noindent` to suppress indentation after a section heading.

Comment: I use `{0pt}` as the 3rd argument. By the way, `{\z@}` means no setting or also set it to 0?

Comment: @Xliu it is 0pt see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/what-does-z-do/55401#55401

Comment: Yes. Just checked. Both works. Thank you.