# Definition of \magstep in Plain TeX

Tags: macros, plain-tex

On page 349 of the TeXbook the definition of `\magstep` is given as

```
\def\magstep#1{\ifcase#1 1000\or
  1200\or 1440\or 1728\or 2074\or 2488\fi\relax}
```

But in `plain.tex` of texlive the line 391 says:

```
\def\magstep#1{\ifcase#1 \@m\or 1200\or 1440\or 1728\or 2074\or 2488\fi\relax}
```

Why does it say `\@m` (which is defined as `\mathchardef\@m=1000`) instead of `1000`?

The version number in the file plain.tex is `\def\fmtversion{3.141592653}` and thus identical to
the version number in the TeXbook.

Comment: I suspect it might be related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55401/2417). However, there are others who know the internals of TeX much better than me.

Comment: @ecki The difference between `1000 ` and `\@m` is duly covered by this provision at the bottom of p. 342 of the TeXbook (appendix B): `Our purpose in the rest of this appendix will be to discuss the contents of
plain.tex. However, we will not include a verbatim description, because some parts of that file are too boring, and because the actual macros have been “optimized” with respect to memory space and running time. Unoptimized versions of the macros are easier for humans to understand, so we shall deal with those; plain.tex contains equivalent constructions that work better on a machine.`

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `\magstep` has always been with `\@m`, as far as I know.

Looking in the SAIL archives [http://www.saildart.org/[TEX,SYS]/](http://www.saildart.org/%5BTEX,SYS%5D/) we can see that `\magstep` made its appearance in the version dated 1983-07-27 and the code is

```
\def\magstephalf{1095 }
\def\magstep#1{\ifcase#1 \@m\or 1200\or 1440\or 1728\or 2074\or 2488\fi\relax}
```

The TeXbook lies every now and then. Small white lies, usually, like in this case. Using `\@m` saves three tokens in memory. On the other hand, the code in appendix B shows `1000` for readability.

Similarly, `plain.tex` has

```
\textfont0=\tenrm \scriptfont0=\sevenrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
\def\rm{\fam\z@\tenrm}
\textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
\def\mit{\fam\@ne} \def\oldstyle{\fam\@ne\teni}
\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
\def\cal{\fam\tw@}
```

but the TeXbook maintans it's

```
\textfont0=\tenrm \scriptfont0=\sevenrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
\def\rm{\fam0 \tenrm}
\textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
\def\mit{\fam1 } \def\oldstyle{\fam1 \teni}
\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
\def\cal{\fam2 }
```

One token instead of two. In 1983 and earlier (and also for several years later) memory was in very short supply and even saving one had its value. Hence, “wasting” a `\dimen` register with `\newdimen\z@ \z@=0pt` saved *a lot* of memory, allowing to say `\z@` instead of `0`  (with a space) or `0pt`  in many places.

Thanks to [frougon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574006/definition-of-magstep-in-plain-tex#comment1445778_574006), here's an appropriate quotation from the TeXbook (p. 342):

> Somewhere in your computer system you should be able to find a file
> called `plain.tex` that contains exactly what has been preloaded into
> the running TeX system that you use. Our purpose in the rest of this
> appendix will be to discuss the contents of `plain.tex`. However, we
> will not include a verbatim description, because some parts of that file
> are too boring, and because the actual macros have been “optimized”
> with respect to memory space and running time. Unoptimized versions of the
> macros are easier for humans to understand, so we shall deal with those;
> `plain.tex` contains equivalent constructions that work better on a machine.