# Why \@M instead of 10000?

Tags: macros, code

Reading code from packages/whatever, I often find commands like `\@M`, `\p@`, `\z@`, `\m@ne`, `\@ne`, `\tw@` etc. What is the point in using those instead of the (IMHO more understandable) `10000`, `pt`, `-1`, `1`, `2` etc?

Comment: I believe this has already been asked.

Comment: This is certainly a dupe, but comes down to saving tokens.

Comment: Possible duplikate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/ne-tw-thr

Comment: This is historical relict. Today, the argument about saving of tokens in macro token space is irrelevant. And the human readability is much more important. Never use the `\m@ne` etc. Of course, you need to put right separator (typical space) after numerical constant.