# use \def\@plus{plus} etc to save token space

Tags: latex-base, definition, token

In the LaTeX kernel, we can see these definitions:

```
\def\@plus{plus}
\def\@minus{minus}
\def\@height{height}
\def\@depth{depth}
\def\@width{width}
```

It is said that these definitions can be used to save token space. How to understand this point of view?

Comment: It is probably not really relevant anymore. It was for back when RAM was more limited. It it has to do with `\@plus` is one token and `plus` is four (each letter)

Comment: Related [programming - Saving a 100 tokens worth, is it worth it? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/saving-a-100-tokens-worth-is-it-worth-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example:

```
\def\stretch#1{\z@ \@plus #1fill\relax}
```

against

```
\def\stretch#1{\z@ plus #1fill\relax}
```

The former needs to store nine tokens, the latter thirteen. Every time `\@plus` is used in a definition, there's a gain of four tokens. The kernel uses `\@plus` fifteen times, so the net gain is 60 tokens.

There are also 26 and 27 appearances of `\@height` and `\@width` respectively.

It may seem rather small, but it allowed LaTeX to run in the nineties. Not to mention `\z@` that can stand for `0` as a constant or `0pt` as a dimension. In the former case the gain is one token per appearance (one for the characters and one for the trailing space).

Comment: Gain of `\@plus` should be three tokens not four, `plus` doesn't require a space, so it's `\z@ plus#1fill` vs `\z@\@plus #1fill`.