# A list of newcommand objects

Tags: macros

I often have a whole bunch of definitions such as

```
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
```

with `R` replaced by `R,Z,C`, etc.

I might also have a bunch of math operators or category definitions, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\cC}{\ensuremath{\mathscr{C}}}
```

What I would love is a way I could define this all at once. For example I could have some function `\bb` that I could just write

```
\bb{Z,R,C,...}

\operators{Hom,Tor,Ext,....}

\category{C,S,H,...}
```

and this would then allow me to just use `\Z` for `\mathbb{Z}` in the document.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48

Comment: Just a remark: I would recommend not using `\ensuremath` with commands like `\N`. I don't think that `$\N$` costs much more typing than `\N`. And imagine you want to write `$-\N$` and you forget the dollars and write `-\N`, then it gets completely different meaning.

Comment: 3 wonderful answers, so I'll go with the community! Thanks to all responders

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list parser `\docsvlist` is an ideal candidate for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% \do to each item in list
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname ##1\endcsname{\ensuremath{\mathbb{##1}}}%
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
}
\begin{document}
\bb{R,N,Z,Q,C}% Create \mathbb macros
Real: \R, Natural: \N, Integer: \Z, Rational: \Q, Complex: \C
\end{document}
```

The macro `\do` is applied to each entry in the CSV list.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\processlist}[3][\relax]{% 
  \def\listfinish{#1}% 
  \long\def\listact{#2}% 
  \processnext#3\listfinish} 
\newcommand{\processnext}[1]{% 
  \ifx\listfinish#1\empty\else\listact{#1}\expandafter\processnext\fi} 

\newcommand{\bb}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\processlist{\bb}{{R}{N}{Z}{Q}}
Real: \R, Natural: \N, Relative: \Z, Fractional: \Q
\end{document}
```

I should add that I combined these [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand) [answers](http://old.nabble.com/Functions-with-a-variable-number-of-parameters-td19297862.html) to come up with the above.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more abstract (and quite shorter) way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 = command to use
% #2 = optional prefix
% #3 = list
\NewDocumentCommand{\createbunch}{ m O{} m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 } { \cs_new_protected:cpn { #2 ##1 } { #1 { ##1 } } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\createbunch{\mathbb}{Z,R,C}

\createbunch{\operatorname}{Hom,Tor,Ext}

\createbunch{\mathcal}[c]{C,S,H}

% This is just for showing the meaning of some of the created macros
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Meaning[1]{\texttt{\string#1: \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\Meaning\Z

\Meaning\R

\Meaning\Hom

\Meaning\cS

\end{document}
```

[image]