# Simplifying Manual Recursion

Tags: loops

The following is literally copied/pasted out of a *.tex file:

```
\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\bB}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\bD}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbf{E}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbf{F}}
\newcommand{\bG}{\mathbf{G}}
\newcommand{\bH}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\bI}{\mathbf{I}}
\newcommand{\bJ}{\mathbf{J}}
\newcommand{\bK}{\mathbf{K}}
\newcommand{\bL}{\mathbf{L}}
\newcommand{\bM}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbf{N}}
\newcommand{\bO}{\mathbf{O}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbf{P}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbf{Q}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbf{R}}
\newcommand{\bS}{\mathbf{S}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbf{T}}
\newcommand{\bU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\bV}{\mathbf{V}}
\newcommand{\bW}{\mathbf{W}}
\newcommand{\bX}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\bY}{\mathbf{Y}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbf{Z}}
```

Is there a way to simplify this by using a for loop of some sort over A-Z?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you intend to simplify? Is this what you're looking for: `\renewcommand{\b}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`?

Comment: @CountZero: edited to add: "looking for for loop"

Comment: Looks similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51353/a-list-of-newcommand-objects/51375

Comment: why do this? If you went `\let\b\mathbf` then you could  use `\b A` so there is really no need to define 26 extra commands for this which just takes up TeX memory, and is slower.

Comment: I find \bA easier to read than \b A. (Purely personal preference.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Isn't there some danger of conflicts with the approach you suggested?

Comment: @Dror do you mean the `\b` suggested in comments or the `\bA` in the answer? Either way, for any macro or package if two packages define the same macro there may be a conflict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `etoolbox` package, you can do the following :

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\parser #1{\expandafter\def\csname b#1\endcsname{\mathbf{#1}}}
\forcsvlist{\parser}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
```

Note that the list you give to `\forcsvlist` could really be anything (besides things containing commas of course).

This loops over the elements of the "comma separated values" list you give it and passes them one by one to the `\parser` macro which defines what you want.

The advantages of this method is that it is very compact and easily readable for the user. 
You can also change quite easily the operation you want to perform, the prefix or the list of strings concerned by your formatting. 
Also, the `etoolbox` will probably be loaded by another package anyway, so you don't load anything new.

The inconvenient is the same as in @DavidCarliste answer. It is quite slower for LaTeX to process. 
However, this effect will not show up until you have really a lot of elements to loop over.

Answer (score 10):

As I mentioned in comments I wouldn't do this. But if I wanted to do it I'd probably do

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter


\count@`\A
\loop
\lccode`\.\count@
\lowercase{\@namedef{b.}{\mathbf.}}%
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@>`\Z\else
\repeat


\show\bA
\show\bC
\show\bZ

\stop
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing there is not a recursion. Recursion means that a function (or macro in `TeX` for that matter) calls (i.e. expands to something containing) itself. You are simply repeating similar code and this certainly can be expressed by a loop.

Nevertheless, I don't think you gain much by this approach. Besides the `\b A` / `\bA` argument, David's code is certainly not a lot faster than your original one. Its not even significantly shorter.

I would simply put those 26 lines into a separate package. So just create a `mathbfcmds.sty` file (in your `PATH`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mathbfcmds}[2012/08/21]

\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}
...
```

and in any `TeX` document you want to use it, you can do `\usepackage{mathbfcmds}`. This way you truly save some effort without obfuscating the code and it doesn't matter whether you add another hundred declarations of that kind.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `pgffor` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}\scrollmode


\makeatletter
\foreach \m in {A,B,C,D,E}
{
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname b\m\endcsname{\mathbf{\m}}
}
\makeatother

$\bA$
$\bD$
$\bC$
$\bE$
$\bB$
\end{document}
```

The code simply uses a foreach to define the macros in a loop. To do this though one must properly expand the loop variable `\m`. It is a bit tricky because the `\mathbf{\m}` is hard to expand. One must use a `\protected@xdef` to make it work. (\xdef alone doesn't seem to work and `\gdef` doesn't seem to allow one to get the second `\m` expanded)

Note that this code blindly defines the macros which may already exist.

Comment: It is possible to write `\foreach \m in {A...Z}` ?

Comment: @canaaerus No but I'm sure it would not be hard to generate a comma separated list of the alphabet. It would probably be easier to type it once and stick in in a macro somewhere and use the macro.

Comment: @canaaerus: Yes, `\foreach \m in {A,...,Z}` works (note the commas). You can also use lower case letters, or a different step size (`{a,c,...,z}` will give `a,c,e,...`).