# Making Preamble File and SyncTeX with Kile (in Linux)

Tags: kile, forward-inverse-search

I am on an `Ubuntu` system with `TeXLive` as my `TeX`-distribution. I would like to write a common style file and include this file in every document. What should the extension of such a file be?

And, another question is: Where should I put this file?

On my computer there is a directory called `/etc/texmf/` and there are some relevant files such as:

1. `tex`
2. `texdoc`

Also, how do I configure `Kile` with `Okular` for `SyncTeX`? That is, I'd like to view the relevant part of my source file on click in the `Okular` window.

Comment: As for the 'where', use this command `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXINPUTS`: it will return a list of where 'latex' searches for files, etc. It will probably mention one like `/home/<user>/texmf`, which means you could put personal `.sty` files in a place like `/home/<user>/texmf/tex/latex/`, and it will be found.  You can do `kpsewhich --var-value=BIBINPUTS` to do similar things for `.bib` files, probably ending up with putting your `.bib` in `/home/<user>/texmf/bibtex/bib`.  The one thing you want to do is make the 'local' tree mimic the system tree in terms of directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a little much for one question. Especially the part about `SyncTeX` should probably be put in a separate question. Also I can only answer the rest.

To put common commands into a dedicated file, you could either just create a simple `mypreamble.tex` file and execute `\input{mypreamble}` to use it. A more sophisticated approach is to write a custom `package`, i.e. a `.sty` file. As I [described before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68015/15616) essentially you only need these two lines:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}[2012/08/23]
```

at the beginning of the `.sty` file, which give the name of your package (in this case the file should be names `mypreamble.sty`) and the date of the last changes. It can be loaded with `\usepackage{mypreamble}`.

In any case you should put the file in a directory where it can be found by `tex`. Of course you don't want to always copy it to the projects directory. Although there may be other ways, I think the best approach for this kind of style file is to put it in a special directory, like e.g. `/home/myname/tex/` and add that directory to the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. Where you can do that depends on the window manager or shell you are using. The command line should look something like this:

```
export TEXINPUTS="$TEXINPUTS:.:/home/myname/tex:"
```

I had to put this line into `~/.zshrc`, but it could also belong into `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or others depending on your setup.

Comment: `\input` rather than `\include` for `.tex` files of commands although `.sty` (and `\usepackage`)is better. (`\include` is really for files with text in like including chapters of a book, and executes `\clearpage` and checkpoints all counters etc.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, seems I mixed that up. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @canaaerus: I got some LaTeX Warning: "You have requested package but the package provides `mypreamble`"---How do I rectify this?

Comment: @user31526: Make sure that the file name matches the packagename in `\ProvidesPackage`. So with my example code you need to name the file `mypreamble.sty`.

Comment: @canaaerus: New problem "You have requested package but the package provides `mypreamble.sty'

Comment: @user31526: You misunderstood me. You give your package a name. If that name is `mypreamble`, you must name the file `mypreamble.sty`, use `\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}[2012/08/24]` in it and in your regular `.tex` file load the package with `\usepackage{mypreamble}`.