# How do I write $\sim$ approximately with the correct spacing?

Tags: spacing, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

I would like to use the symbol `$\sim$` as "approximately". e.g:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
There are $\sim 10^{80}$ atoms in the universe.
\end{document}
```

I think that I need to declare `$\sim$` as some sort of unary math operator, to make the spacing correct! How?

**Edit:**

Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde it can be read, that `$\sim$` can be used both as a binary relation operator, and an unary operator meaning "approximately".

> Common use
>
> This symbol (in English) sometimes means "approximately", such as:
> "~30 minutes ago" meaning "approximately 30 minutes ago".[2] It can
> mean "similar to",[3] including "of the same order of magnitude
> as",[4] such as: x ~ y" meaning that x and y are of the same order of
> magnitude. Another approximation symbol is ≈, meaning "approximately
> equal to."

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators

Comment: `\sim` is a relation symbol, and usually one *wants* some space between it and the following object. If you want no space (but I would avoid it), then `${\sim}10^{80}$` will do.

Comment: For a symbol that indicates approximate equality, you may want to consider using `$\approx$` instead of `$\sim$.

Comment: @Mico: Yes - I would use `$\approx$` for "approximate equal". e.g `$\pi \approx 3.14`. -but it looks wrong(ugly) for "approximately" as in my example.

Comment: @egreg: Yes for a relation, I would definitely want the space, but not for the unary operator. Your solution looks good, but I am looking for the correct way to make `$\sim$` behave nicely. (minus ,`-` can also be both unary and binary e.g. `$2-5=-3$`

Comment: For manual modification of spacing around operators, see [How to change default for space around binary operators?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55512/5764)

Comment: I question the assumption that `\sim` is used as unary operator in your example, but rather a binary relation with one side implied in the natural language part of the sentence, similar to "The circumference of a circle is `$\approx 3.14$` times the diameter"  or "When playing Musical Chairs, the number of chairs is the number of players `${}-1$` (not: `$-1$`)". -- And yes, under many circumstances, such things look awful and one should consider less obtrusive mixtures of natural and language and math formulas

Comment: Note that in some contexts, the tilde symbol is used as a unary operator meaning "Not". That's another use case for not wanting the pesky space between the operator and the literal.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `\sim` symbol is classified as a relation symbol. By the rules of TeX, the combination **Rel Ord** (relation followed by an ordinary symbol) results in a thick space between them.

The case of binary operations (**Bin**) is different: they are treated as binary operations *only* if preceded *and* followed by math atoms compatible with binary operations, for instance

> **Ord Bin Ord**
>   **Ord Bin Op**

and others (**Op** stands for "operator"). [*This is not the full truth, but a good approximation to it.*] When a binary operation is "out of place", it's treated as an **Ord** atom. This is why no space is inserted in `$-1$`.

Every math symbol can be turned into an ordinary atom by enclosing it in braces. TeX inserts no space between ordinary symbols, so

```
$\sim 10^{80}$
```

will result in

> ~ 10<sup>80</sup>

while

```
${\sim}10^{80}$
```

will give

> ~10<sup>80</sup>

I'm afraid that no automatic way exists that allows using only `\sim`. You can define

```
\newcommand{\unsim}{\mathord{\sim}}
```

(the `\mathord` is just for clarity, the additional braces would do the same) and use `\unsim` when the "unary" symbol is needed.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, wanting to use `\sim` for the (unary) logical negation operator.  Building on egreg's answer from above, another option is to simply redefine the `\sim` command so that it produces the tilde without the space:

```
\let\oldsim\sim 
\renewcommand{\sim}{{\oldsim}}
```