# Making a unary operator out of a binary operator or relation symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

Often in physics, the symbol `\sim` is used as a unary operator to mean "approximately."

For example, one might say "`the energy of these processes is $\sim 4$ eV.`" However, this looks awkward because `\sim` is a binary operator and the spacing is incorrect. How can one use `\sim` act as a unary operator?

Comment: `${\sim}4$` or `$\mathord{\sim}4$`

Comment: `\sim` is a relation symbol, rather than a binary operation; if it were then `$\sim 4$` would give no space. It's probably better to define a new command for it as an "Ord": `\newcommand{\appx}{{\sim}}`. Consider using `siunitx` for typesetting units of measure.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55701

Comment: Related: [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/16595)

Comment: I had exactly the same question. Now that I understand the nice answer below, my question is, how does the unary minus not need a separate command?  If we give the same treatment to the `\sim` symbol as the minus symbol, that would automatically solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just define a new command for it:

```
\newcommand{\ca}{{\sim}}
```

I suggest also to use `siunitx`, if you have units of measure to typeset in your document: it ensures uniform setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ca}{{\sim}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-protect-tokens=\ca,input-symbols=\ca}

\begin{document}
\SI{\ca 4}{eV}

$\ca 4$\,eV
\end{document}
```

The input might seem more difficult, but it's surely rewarding.

[image]

If you load `amssymb` you can change the definition to

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\ca}{{\thicksim}}
```

and the result would be

[image]