# How do I write $\sim$ approximately with the correct spacing using siunitx?

Tags: spacing, siunitx, math-operators

This question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55701/how-do-i-write-sim-approximately-with-the-correct-spacing), only that I'm using the siunitx package:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The temperature is \SI{\sim 200}{\kelvin}. \\
The temperature is \SI{{\sim} 200}{\kelvin}. \\
The temperature is \SI{{\sim}200}{\kelvin}. \\
The temperature is $\sim$\SI{200}{\kelvin}.
\end{document}
```

The last line leads to the result I want. It is however not very elegant in my oppinion. Is there a way to tell the si package that I don't want a space before  my value?

Comment: You could `\newcommand{\unsim}{\mathord{\sim}}` and use that in `\SI{{\unsim}200}{\kelvin}` or `\SI{{\unsim} 200}{\kelvin}`. Or even better `\newcommand{\appr}{{\mathord{\sim}}}` (the double curly braces are important) and `\SI{\appr 200}{\kelvin}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Should you not use `\approx`?

Comment: In some fields, `\sim`, is used to mean "approximately". And I've only ever seen `\approx` mean "is approximately equal to" rather than merely "approximately", so `T \approx 200` would be a correct use of it but `The temperature is \approx 200` would not. (Please excuse lack of math mode and unit signifiers unnecessary to make this point.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since version 2.1 `siunitx` supports so called `comparators` such as `<`, `=`, `>` and also `\approx` and `\sim`. In version 2.6 the spacing for these was fixed such that

```
\SI{\sim 200}{\kelvin}
```

now gives exactly what you want.
See also `input-comparators` on p. 21 of the [`siunitx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).

MWE: compare this solution (first line) to your desired output (second line)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The temperature is \SI{\sim 200}{\kelvin}.

The temperature is $\sim$\SI{200}{\kelvin}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\approx`, instead of define `\appr`. Also, the 2nd example looks like a big hack to me.

Comment: @jmc I would have liked to use `\approx`, but that macro is already defined and yields ≈. (Whether one *should* use the ∼ or ≈ symbol here is an entirely different matter.) The second example is just to compare my solution the OP's preferred output.

Comment: That gives me an error: `! Missing } inserted.` It's non fatal, but requires me to click enter to continue....

Comment: @TheChymera Ah yes, thanks for the heads-up. `siunitx` has drastically improves support for `\sim` and friends since I wrote this. It is now enough to do `\SI{\sim 200}{\kelvin}`. You should never ignore an error by pressing enter even if the result seems all right (but of course you knew that, otherwise you wouldn't have commented).

Answer (score 6):

`~` is a relational symbol and should be used such.  Further you can use `\SI` macro inside the math mode. Hence, the correct way is

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}    
\begin{document}
The temperature is $\sim\SI{200}{\kelvin}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could add one sentence, why this is correct. The *but* stands so alone there.

Comment: @Johannes_B OK, I added the reason. Thanks :)

Comment: It's the same here for `~` as for `<`: You always write `$x$ is in modulus $<1$` and not `... in modulus $<$1`.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you mean this solely in a programming context? Because I was referring mainly to the typography of my text and especially with single digit numbers the rather huge distance to the ~ looks a bit strange to me. In the scientific literature connected to my work I've found both notations so I don't know if there is a "right" one.

Comment: @LukasBrunner No, this is a math thing. Think of the difference between minus as a unary and binary operator, for example `3 - -2=5`

Comment: No. In this question `~` is NOT a relational symbol, it is an unary operator. Look at the question, that OP links to.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen In physics, it is `~ 200K` and not `~200K`. This appears to be physics related. In the question, the OP doesn't want `~` to be relational but unary (I know) but that, according to me, is not correct. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: Ok - I see your point, but I(and wikipedia) do not agree. My question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55701/how-do-i-write-sim-approximately-with-the-correct-spacing and wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde explains the two different uses.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Good luck with that delusion.

Comment: Actually, I thought in physics, we should write ~ 200 K ?

Answer (score 1):

The result of

```
Lichtgeschwindigkeit (\SI{\sim300000}{\kilo\meter\per\second}) Richtung Erde
```

is

[image]

without space between

Answer (score 0):

Like Raphael said in the comments:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The temperature is $\approx \SI{200}{\kelvin}$.
\end{document}
```