# How do I reduce the space between operators in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I have these operators `+=`, `-=` etc. in Math mode.
LaTeX introduces space around single character operators. So I get + = and - = instead.

However, in my case I want no space between the + and the =, and similarly between the - and the = in the second operator.

How do I make them near each other such that there are is no horizontal space between them? I tried to put them in `\mathit` but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: i'm sure this has been asked before, hence a comment, not an answer.  wrap each operator in braces, and wrap the whole thing in `\mathrel`, like this:  `\mathrel{{+}{=}}' and `\mathrel{{=}{+}}`.

Comment: Cheers, I tried to look around but sometimes its a problem to find these things without the right keywords!

Comment: If you are trying to write C code, you might look at the listings package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. No its not source code. Its still in math mode, defining a transition function of a state with numeric variables. (Its a bit weird I know, I didn't invent it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the two symbols aren't in the same class, so they'll invariably get
some space in between.

to turn an operator or a relation into an "ordinary" character, wrap it
in braces.  then, combine them and wrap the whole thing in braces, applying
`\mathbin` or `\mathrel` as appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ a \mathbin{{+}{=}} b \mathrel{{=}{+}} c \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

(i'm still sure this has been covered before.)

The operator can also be defined in the preamble so that it can be reused:

```
\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathbin{{+}{=}}}
```

Comment: It has been touched here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55701/how-do-i-write-sim-approximately-with-the-correct-spacing

Comment: Thanks. I think one can actually also define an operator as follows: `\DeclareMathOperator{\pluseq}{\mathbin{{+}{=}}}`

Comment: @jbx No, `\DeclareMathOperator` is not the right way; just `\newcommand` is what you need.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Yes with `\DeclareMathOperator` it seems to show it in a different way. For example the `*` is vertically aligned to the top, while with your way its correct. Not sure why, but at least it works fine.