# Defining new commands inside a for loop

Tags: macros, expansion, loops

I would like to define a number of related commands by using the counter in a for-loop.

For example, I want to define 26 commands like this:

```
\newcommand{\calA}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\calB}{{\cal B}}
...
```

I've been searching for a while (and have in fact learned quite a bit), but have still not found the answer. Here's my latest attempt (it uses the `forloop` package):

```
\newcounter{ct}
\forLoop{1}{26}{ct}{
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter%
    {\csname cal\Alph{ct}\endcsname}%
    {{\cal \Alph{ct}}}
}
```

All 26 commands are created, but are all defined as `{\cal Z}`. I guess `{\cal \Alph{ct}}` is only expanded after the loop has completed.

How can I accomplish my goal? And how does it work?

Comment: There's a related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48/86 (I'm pretty sure we've had an even closer one, but I can't find it right now).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't say which package you got your loop macro from. This just uses the `\loop` in LaTeX (originally from plain TeX)

```
> \calA=\long macro:
->\mathcal {A}.
l.18 \show\calA

? 
> \calZ=\long macro:
->\mathcal {Z}.
l.20 \show\calZ
```

produced from

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\foo#1{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname cal#1\endcsname{\mathcal{#1}}}

\count@=0
\loop
\advance\count@ 1
\edef\y{\@Alph\count@}%
\expandafter\foo\y
\ifnum\count@<26
\repeat



\show\calA

\show\calZ

\stop
```

Comment: I was using the `forloop` package. I aded this information to my question.

Comment: Your answer seems to work fine! But I'd like to know how it works, and why my code doesn't work (this sort of code is a bit new to me). Preferably I'd like to see it done with a more LaTeXy for-loop as well, if you'd be so kind. :-)

Comment: I've mixed your code and mine into a more LaTeXy solution, and put it down as a separate answer. Thanks!

Comment: well I can't say much about yours as I commented you didn't provide a MWE or say where the macro came from. I may comment on mine later but have to attend to the day job for a bit:-)

Answer (score 10):

These types of constructs are better done, either through LaTeX2e, kernel commands and constructs, hard core TeX or with a package such as etoolbox (or LaTeX3).

In this case I would prefer the following approach.

Firstly define a command that will define the other commands. Let us call it `\commandfactory`.

```
  \def\commandfactory#1{%
     \expandafter\def\csname cal#1\endcsname{\mathcal{#1}}}
```

We will need a new counter to keep track of the iteration and to provide the "letters" for the command.

```
   \newcounter{ctr}
```

The easiest looping structure in this case will be Knuth's `\loop..\repeat` construct.
Finally, the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\commandfactory#1{%
   \expandafter\def\csname cal#1\endcsname{\mathcal{#1}}}

\newcounter{ctr}
\loop
  \stepcounter{ctr}
  \edef\X{\@Alph\c@ctr}%
  \expandafter\commandfactory\X
\ifnum\thectr<26
\repeat

\begin{document}
\setcounter{ctr}{0}
\loop
  \stepcounter{ctr}
   $\@nameuse{cal\@Alph\c@ctr}$, 
\ifnum\thectr<26
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Why I normally prefer such approach is that it uses constructs that are very common in packages and the kernel (i.e, you use common paradigms) and is easy to find information. People sometimes object to hybrid TeX/LaTeX commands, but hey, the important thing is for your code to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be the same as David's answer. :-) It was quite helpful, but I do tend to prefer the somewhat higher-level constructs. They're a bit more readable, and the `forloop` package does seem widely supported.

Comment: @mhelvens They are very similar, i just prefer not to use \count@1, advance etc. Wanted to illustrate a reasonable hybrid and I didn't like `\expandafter\newcommand`.

Answer (score 10):

Aha, no TikZ related answers! Unacceptable....

You can also use the [`pgffor`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) module of the PGF/TikZ package externally. This also gives you a chance to iterate over letters directly. I have used the `ensuremath` to use it directly but you can remove that and the corresponding `\noexpand`. See [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) for more info on that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in {A,...,Z}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname cal\x\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathcal{\x}}}
}
\begin{document}
\calP\calG\calF / \calT\calI\calK\calZ
\end{document}
```

[image]

I fear that I'll have a tattoo out of this in the end.

**EDIT** Provided by Andrew Stacey

A XeLaTeX solution with even fancier calligraphy and correct capitalization

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\AtBeginDocument{
\foreach \x in {A,...,Z}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname cal\x\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\csname mscr\x\endcsname}}
}
\foreach \x in {a,...,z}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname cal\x\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\csname mscr\x\endcsname}}
}
}
\begin{document}
\calP\calG\calF / \calT\cali\calK\calZ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of that syntax. But I'm getting errors. I ran your exact code, and got a lot of `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: That's interesting I can compile without any problems. You can add `\listfiles` in your preanble and check the version of PGF/TikZ package components in the log messages. I have 2.10.

Comment: v2.00 here. I guess that must be it? I'll try and find a newer version.

Comment: It seems to be more tricky than a single .sty file. In the end I think I'll stick with the `\forLoop` solution. It works, and seems to be more widely supported. Thanks!

Comment: What I meant was that the `forloop` package is installed in TexLive, which all my colleagues use. Apparently that particular version of `pgffor` is not.

Comment: @mhelvens No worries :) I just wanted to let you know about it but TeXLive users usually go for vanilla but I have no idea as I am an ignorant PC user with MikTeX installed.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer of David Carlisle, I've altered my own solution as follows:

```
\newcommand{\defcal} [1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname cal#1\endcsname{{\cal #1}}}
\newcounter{ct}
\forLoop{1}{26}{ct}{
    \edef\letter{\Alph{ct}}
    \expandafter\defcal\letter
}
```

The trick seems to be to create the `\defcal` command, then use `\edef`, as well as `\expandafter`, so its argument is expanded first.

Comment: Please, don't use the deprecated syntax `{\cal A}`, but rather `\mathcal{A}`.

Answer (score 5):

> The forloop package defines two commands \forloop (preferred usage)
>   and \forLoop (deprecated).

The definition of forloop is

> ```
> \forloop[⟨step⟩]{⟨counter⟩}{⟨initial value⟩}{⟨condition⟩}{⟨code⟩}
> ```

But it's not the problem here. Your problem comes from the expansion of `\Alph{ct}`.
A lot of answers are fine, here I use something like percusse and you can see you can use `\forloop` instead of `\foreach`

But I disagree with :

> They're a bit more readable, and the forloop package does seem widely

because if you compare percusse's answer with my answer, I don't see what is more readable. 
Now in this case, I think it's better to do like  David and to avoid `\forloop`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forloop}
\makeatletter 
\let\FOR\@for
\let\NAMEUSE\@nameuse   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{ct} 
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 27}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname cal\Alph{ct}\endcsname{%
\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathcal{\Alph{ct}}}}
}

\FOR\letter:={A,L,T,E,R,M,U,N,D,U,S}\do{% 
\NAMEUSE{cal\letter}}

\end{document}
```

Pub !

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update 5 Jun 2012:**

Today the LaTeX3 team changed some internal function names of the type `\prg_`. The function `\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn` will be renamed to.

So if you use the newest version of `expl3` you have to use `\int_step_inline:nnnn` instead of `\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn`. The syntax is the same. For more details have a look at the announcement:

[Deprecated functions: \prg_.. functions and x-type expansion based on \pdfstrcmp](http://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=LATEX-L;8d862f81.1206)

---

To complete the list I want to provide a solution with `expl3`. Therefor you can use the function `\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn` with the following syntax:

```
\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn {<starting point>}
                          {<step>}
                          {<end point>}
                          {<code>}
```

For your request I used:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn {1 } { 1 } { 26 } 
 { 
 \cs_new:cpn { cal \int_to_Alph:n { #1 } } { \mathcal{ \int_to_Alph:n { #1 } } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn {1 } { 1 } { 26 } 
 { 
  $\use:c{ cal \int_to_Alph:n { #1 } }$
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]